# How to loop through a HashMap in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, loops, hashmap

How can I loop through a `HashMap` in JSP?

```
<%
    HashMap<String, String> countries = MainUtils.getCountries(l);
%>

<select name="country">
    <% 
        // Here I need to loop through countries.
    %>
</select>
```

Comment: By the way, a `HashMap` is by nature unordered. Are you certain you don't need `TreeMap` (automagic sort by key) or `LinkedHashMap` (maintains insertion order)?

Answer (score 325):

Just the same way as you would do in normal Java code.

```java
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : countries.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    String value = entry.getValue();
    // ...
}
```

---

**However**, *scriptlets* (raw Java code in JSP files, those `<% %>` things) are considered a [poor practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/howto-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202). I recommend to install [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info). It has a [`<c:forEach>`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/tags/3.0/tagdocs/c/foreach) tag which can iterate over among others `Map`s. Every iteration will give you a [`Map.Entry`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.Entry.html) back which in turn has `getKey()` and `getValue()` methods.

Here's a basic example:

```xml
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="jakarta.tags.core" %>

<c:forEach items="${map}" var="entry">
    Key = ${entry.key}, value = ${entry.value}<br>
</c:forEach>
```

Thus your particular issue can be solved as follows:

```xml
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="jakarta.tags.core" %>

<select name="country">
    <c:forEach items="${countries}" var="country">
        <option value="${country.key}">${country.value}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

You need a `Servlet` or a `ServletContextListener` to place the `${countries}` in the desired scope. If this list is supposed to be request-based, then use the `Servlet`'s `doGet()`:

```java
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    Map<String, String> countries = MainUtils.getCountries();
    request.setAttribute("countries", countries);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/page.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

Or if this list is supposed to be an application-wide constant, then use `ServletContextListener`'s `contextInitialized()` so that it will be loaded only once and kept in memory:

```java
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
    Map<String, String> countries = MainUtils.getCountries();
    event.getServletContext().setAttribute("countries", countries);
}
```

In both cases the `countries` will be available in [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) by `${countries}`.

#### See also:

- [Iterate over elements of List and Map using JSTL <c:forEach> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148658/iterate-over-elements-of-list-and-map-using-jstl-cforeach-tag/)
- [How to iterate over a nested map in <c:forEach>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141464/how-to-iterate-over-a-nested-map-in-cforeach/)
- [How to iterate an ArrayList inside a HashMap using JSTL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117557/how-to-iterate-an-arraylist-inside-a-hashmap-using-jstl/)
- [Using special auto start servlet to initialize on startup and share application data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468150/using-special-auto-start-servlet-to-initialize-on-startup-and-share-application)

Comment: @Khue: yes, you can also put attributes in the session. I only don't see why you would like to duplicate application wide data over multiple sessions.

Comment: I think in case of session-based info. Thanks for the very nice explanation.

Comment: I'm sure the answer is obvious but - why are scriptlets considered poor practice?  In the absence of JSTL due to maintaining a legacy application, this is my only option.

Comment: @Zibbobz: the text "poor practice" is a link. Click on it.

Answer (score 0):

Below code works for me

first I defined the `partnerTypesMap` like below in the server side,

```
Map<String, String> partnerTypes = new HashMap<>();
```

after adding values to it I added the object to `model`,

```
model.addAttribute("partnerTypesMap", partnerTypes);
```

When rendering the page I use below `foreach` to print them one by one.

```
<c:forEach items="${partnerTypesMap}" var="partnerTypesMap">
      <form:option value="${partnerTypesMap['value']}">${partnerTypesMap['key']}</form:option>
</c:forEach>
```