# How to iterate an ArrayList inside a HashMap using JSTL?

Tags: java, jsp, dictionary, arraylist, jstl

I have a map like this,

```
Map<Integer,ArrayList<Object>> myMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer,ArrayList<Object>>();
```

Now I have to iterate this Map and then the ArrayList inside the map. How can I do this using JSTL?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can use [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) [`<c:forEach>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html) tag to iterate over arrays, collections and maps.

In case of arrays and collections, every iteration the `var` will give you just the currently iterated item right away.

```html
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<c:forEach items="${collectionOrArray}" var="item">
    Item = ${item}<br>
</c:forEach>
```

In case of maps, every iteration the `var` will give you a [`Map.Entry`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) object which in turn has `getKey()` and `getValue()` methods.

```html
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<c:forEach items="${map}" var="entry">
    Key = ${entry.key}, value = ${entry.value}<br>
</c:forEach>
```

In your particular case, the `${entry.value}` is actually a `List`, thus you need to iterate over it as well:

```html
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<c:forEach items="${map}" var="entry">
    Key = ${entry.key}, values = 
    <c:forEach items="${entry.value}" var="item" varStatus="loop">
        ${item} ${!loop.last ? ', ' : ''}
    </c:forEach><br>
</c:forEach>
```

The `varStatus` is there just for convenience ;)

To understand better what's all going on here, here's a plain Java translation:

```java
for (Entry<String, List<Object>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    out.print("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", values = ");
    for (Iterator<Object> iter = entry.getValue().iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
        Object item = iter.next();
        out.print(item + (iter.hasNext() ? ", " : ""));
    }
    out.println();
}
```

#### See also:

- [How to loop through a HashMap in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835683/how-to-loop-through-a-hashmap-in-jsp)
- [Show JDBC ResultSet in HTML in JSP page using MVC and DAO pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003142/show-jdbc-resultset-in-html-table-in-jsp-page-using-mvc-pattern)
- [How to loop over something a specified number of times in JSTL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099066/how-to-loop-over-something-a-specified-number-of-times-in-jstl/)

Comment: i like the way u used '${!loop.last ? ', ' : ''}' :D

Comment: You can find more methods here: http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus.html The `${loop.index}`, `${loop.first}` and `${loop.last}` are most useful here.

Comment: yay ! Thanks for this post. This matches exactly my case which uses map.value as a list :)

Comment: <c:forEach> should be terminated by </c:forEach>

Comment: Elvis has left the building ?:

Comment: @BalusC I also have similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22293665/how-to-show-multiple-tables-depending-on-key-in-the-map-using-jstl) on the JSTL stuff. See if you can help me out.. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Did you try something like this?

```
<c:forEach var='item' items='${map}'>
    <c:forEach var='arrayItem' items='${item.value}' />
      ...
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: And of course, you might want to output `${item.key}` between the two foreach statements.

Answer (score 5):

you haven't closed c tag.try out this

```
 <c:forEach items="${logMap}" var="entry">
        Key = ${entry.key}, values = 
        <c:forEach items="${entry.value}" var="item" varStatus="loop">
            ${item} ${!loop.last ? ', ' : ''}
        </c:forEach><br>
    </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also loop round just the map.value its self if you know the key

```
<c:forEach var="value" items="${myMap[myObject.someInteger]}">
    ${value}
</c:forEach>
```