# Loop through a Map with JSTL

Tags: dictionary, loops, jstl

I'm looking to have JSTL loop through a `Map<String, String>` and output the value of the key and it's value.

For example I have a `Map<String, String>` which can have any number of entries, i'd like to loop through this map using JSTL and output both the key and it's value.

I know how to access the value using the key, `${myMap['keystring']}`, but how do I access the key?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117557/how-to-iterate-an-arraylist-inside-a-hashmap-using-jstl

Answer (score 285):

Like this:

```
<c:forEach var="entry" items="${myMap}">
  Key: <c:out value="${entry.key}"/>
  Value: <c:out value="${entry.value}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Note to others: do not try to name var in forEach loop "param"

Comment: How can i change the value dynamically withing forEach.

Example.

  <c:forEach var="entry" items="${myMap}">

 <!-- Change the entry.key and entry.value to some other value then the one coming from 
      Map -->

 Key: <c:out value="${entry.key}"/>
 Value: <c:out value="${entry.value}"/>

</c:forEach>

Answer (score 6):

You can loop through a hash map like this

```
<%
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
TreeMap itemList=new TreeMap();
itemList.put("test", "test");
list.add(itemList);
pageContext.setAttribute("itemList", list);                            
%>

  <c:forEach items="${itemList}" var="itemrow">
   <input  type="text"  value="<c:out value='${itemrow.test}'/>"/>
  </c:forEach>
```

For more JSTL functionality look [here](http://fundapass.blogspot.in/2012/06/1024x768-normal-0-false-false-false-en.html)

Comment: Don't use scriplets. They are bad.

Comment: @tad I've also heard that. But why?

Comment: @TJ- As a general rule, there are few good reasons to put powerful logic in your templates; they are hard to debug, they mix paradigms, and they can produce unexpected results. Besides, the JSTL aready provides a facility to cleanly iterate over maps: the forEach tag.

Comment: @tad he's obviously using scriplets to set up his test data. This was a perfectly good answer

Comment: @jk: I agree. The downvotes here are pretty ridic. Also, the idea that scriptlets can produce unexpected results makes no sense to me. They're not pretty, but 1+1 always equals 2, unless there are some specific scenarios I'm not aware of.

Comment: @jk. - while the use of a scriptlet to show the setup for the example is reasonable, expecting your data to be provided as a list of maps with constant keys rather than a map between the actual items you care about is a particularly poor solution to the problem, and I imagine that a lot of people are therefore assuming that the scriptlet is intended to show how to *transform* an existing map into a list, rather than as a way of showing example data.