# JSTL print array list values in ul - li html tag. Right Algorithm.

Tags: java, arrays, jsp, jstl

in a JSP I should print the values of an array list in the "li" html tags. The problem is that I should print in one cycle two values. This is the example in html:

```
<ul class="myProfileTeamNameList">
    <li><p class="first">- Team_Name_1</p><p>- Team_Name_2</p></li>
</ul>
```

I have implemented this but I can only print the first value. This is my code:

```
<ul class="myProfileTeamNameList">
   <c:forEach var="team" items="${teams}">
   <li><p class="first">- ${team.name}</p> <p>- ${team.name}</p></li>
</c:forEach>
</ul>
```

instead in the second

html tag I should write the SUCCESSIVE array list value. Something like:  ${team.name} + 1

Can someone help me? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you should not use a list. You should use a [`Map`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), and [loop through its entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848332/loop-through-a-map-with-jstl) to get the key and value.

But if you really need to use the list, [`<c:forEach>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html) allows you to write a index-based loop. Instead of `items`, specify `step=2`, `begin`, `end` and `varStatus` and then refer to `${items[varStatus.index]}` (and `.index+1` respectively). E.g.

```
<c:forEach step="2" being="0" end="${fn:length(array)}" varStatus="status">
    ${items[varStatus.index]} - ${items[varStatus.index+1]}
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Can you give me a practice example. I have don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to achieve what you want is to pass to the jsp view a list of couple. I mean you could build a teamsInPair list of beans containing the two elements of team. This kind of choice could simplify your business logic in the view.

Comment: Can you give me a practice example. I have don't understand what you mean.