# How to iterate List of List items of Mapped objects in JSP?

Tags: java, list, jsp, view, loops

I have a requirement of displaying data from List> in JSP. so how to do it in JSP?
What would be the best approach to do that?
Eg;

```
List<Map> list=new ArrayList<Map>();
```

List of Mapping objects...
we will add list objects to mainList. It will be like this..

```
List<List> mainList=new ArrayList<List>();
```

Thanks in advance!!!
Earlier reply Highly Appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

Use `<c:forEach>`

for `List<List> list`

```
<c:forEach items="list" var="listOuter">

  <c:forEach items="listOuter" var="listInner">

  </c:forEach>

</c:forEach>
```

---

**Also See**

- [help-jstl-foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387174/help-jstl-foreach)
- [loop-through-a-map-with-jstl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848332/loop-through-a-map-with-jstl)

Comment: There he has taken only List<person>.But here it is too complex like List<List<Map>>.. so can you please explain in detail..

Comment: I think you have a cut&paste error there, the seconds forEach should be:  <c:forEach items="listOuter" var="listInner">

Comment: @John thanks! updated it, btw it was not cut & paste, it was mistake in hand written code :)

Comment: Thank you guys for immediate reply