# Bind arraylist value to JSP dropdown list

Tags: java, jsp

I have a arraylist with some data. I need to bind that data to a dropdown list in JSP and get the selected index. Can any one help me for this?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [JSTL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) [`c:forEach`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html) to iterate over a list (if not done yet, just drop [jstl-1.2.jar](http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar) in `/WEB-INF/lib` to install it).

```
<select name="item">
    <c:forEach items="${list}" var="item">
        <option value="${item.value}">${item.label}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

This assumes that you've a `List<Item>` where `Item` look like this:

```
public class Item {
    private String value;
    private String label;
    // Add/generate c'tors, getters and setters.
}
```

In the server side you can obtain the selected item as follows:

```
String selectedItem = request.getParameter("item");
```

You can alternatively also use a `Map<String, String>` instead of a `List<Item>` where `Item` is actually a key-value pair. You can then iterate over it the following way:

```
<select name="item">
    <c:forEach items="${map}" var="entry">
        <option value="${entry.key}">${entry.value}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

#### Related answers:

- [Loop through Map in JSP/Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117557/how-to-iterate-an-arraylist-inside-a-hashmap-using-jstl/2117678#2117678)
- [Hidden features of JSP/Servlets](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2010/01/hidden-features-of-jspservlet.html)
- [How to avoid Java code in JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/howto-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202)

---

**Update:** As per the comments, you should **never** copy server-specific libraries like `Tomcat/lib/*.*` into the webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` or anywhere else in (default) runtime classpath (e.g. `JRE/lib/ext`). This would only lead to collisions in the classpath which leads to this kind of errors and it will make your webapp unrunnable and unportable. You should keep the server-specific libraries at their default location. Cleanup the `/WEB-INF/lib` from any server-specific libraries.

You probably copied server-specific libraries there because you wasn't able to compile your servlets. Copying the libraries in `/WEB-INF/lib` is the wrong solution. You should basically just specify those libraries in the compiletime classpath. It's unclear which IDE you're using, but if it's Eclipse, this can be done easily: first add the server in *Servers* view, then associate your dynamic webapp project with the added server. On a brand new web project you can choose the server during project creation wizard. On existing web projects, you can modify it in *Targeted Runtimes* section in project's properties. This way Eclipse will automatically add the server-specific libraries to the project's buildpath.

Comment: hey thanks for reply.. in my bean class i got arraylist and return it.after that i did the things you said

this is my jsp

<select name="item">
    <c:forEach items="${item.list}" var="name">
        <option value="<c:out value="${name}" />">
    </c:forEach>
</select>

if i run this

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext.getELContext()Ljavax/el/ELContext;
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:460)

and some root cause exceptios..

i added some additional jars in to web-inf/lib and version of xml is 2.4
confused..

Comment: Post the root causes. They tell something about the root causes of the problem.

Comment: this is one ...

root cause 

javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext.getELContext()Ljavax/el/ELContext;
 org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:841)
 org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:774)
 org.apache.jsp.Onto_0020web_jsp._jspService(Onto_0020web_jsp.java:104)
 org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:331)

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext.getELContext()Ljavax/el/ELContext;
 javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagSupport.unExposeVariables(LoopTagSupport.java:587)
 javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagSupport.doFinally(LoopTagSupport.java:323)
 org.apache.jsp.Onto_0020web_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(Onto_0020web_jsp.java:145)
 org.apache.jsp.Onto_0020web_jsp._jspService(Onto_0020web_jsp.java:89)
 org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)

Comment: this is a exception...

exception 

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext.getELContext()Ljavax/el/ELContext;
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:460)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:355)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:321)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:257)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)

Comment: i added jsp-api  and servlet-api and el-api by reading some forums and also check the version of the server in my xml file(2.4)... also give the same error that i mentined above..

thanks

Comment: Get rid of all server specific libraries in webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib`!! It would only conflict with the ones of the server where you're running the webapp on. Leave the server specific libraries there in the server implementation and don't ever touch/copy/move them.

Comment: thanks for ur quick reply...still confusing...

i added that files in to web-inf/lib folder...just copy and paste....
which lib should i remove from the lib folder..

thanks ...

Comment: i removed the all the libs from web-inf folder.. but still getting the same error.. i put those lib in to web-inf folder because that error occurs when i compile firstly.. i thought the error occurs with my jstl lib...

how can i fix...

Comment: error triggered with my jstl tags.. my servlet version is 2.4 . then i added jstl and standard.jar in to web-inf folder.. then there is no error.. and i changed my taglib as, <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" prefix="c" %> no errors..

thanks for your involvement..