# How to loop over something a specified number of times in JSTL?

Tags: jsp, loops, jstl

I need a while loop within JSTL. I cannot seem to find how to loop over something a specified number of times. Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

I am thinking I could use a forEach but I do not really care to loop over a collection.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

The [`<c:forEach>` tag](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/tags/1.2/tagdocs/c/foreach) is definitely suitable for this. It has `begin` and `end` attributes where you can specify the, well, begin and end. It has a `varStatus` attribute which puts a [`LoopTagStatus` object](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/looptagstatus) in the loop tag scope which in turn has several methods like `getIndex()` and on.

Here's a kickoff example:

```
<c:forEach begin="0" end="10" varStatus="loop">
    Index: ${loop.index}<br/>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: @jon20usa Check out the [JSTL Tag Reference](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) to learn the finer details about these tags.

Comment: @elekwent: The blueish parts in my answer are links already :)

Comment: Ahh, so they are. Oops, I meant to add that comment to the original question.

Comment: @elekwent: ah OK, no problem. You can also find more info and links in our [JSTL tag wiki page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info). Hover the `[jstl]` tag below the question until a popbox shows and click the *info* link there.