# How do i use a for loop in a servlet class?

Tags: java, html, servlets

I have an index file and a servlet class file. I need to create a table after i submit information from the index to the servlet class. I submit the form.

```
        <form name="form" method="post" action="servlet">
        Number: <input type="number" name="table"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
```

This information is passed to the servlet as a number. I need to make tables with the number. If it is 1, it is 1 row, if iti s 5 it is 5 rows. I need to use a for loop on the servlet page, but i am stuck. I have tried something like below, but it does not work.

```
<table>
      <% for(int row=1; row <= 5; row++) { %>
      <tr>
      </tr>
      <% } %>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to avoid Scriplets. You can use [**forEach**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html) JSTL tag for looping in jsp file itself.

set the `count` as request attribute in the servlet and then access it in jsp as shown below:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
...
<c:forEach begin="0" end="${count}" varStatus="loop">
    Index: ${loop.index}<br/>
</c:forEach>
```

Read [How to loop over something a specified number of times in JSTL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099066/how-to-loop-over-something-a-specified-number-of-times-in-jstl)

**Complete example:**

HTML:

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="servlet">
    Number: <input type="number" name="table"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
 </form>
```

Servlet

```
//inside doPost method

    request.setAttribute("count", request.getParameter("table");

    // redirect to jsp 

    String nextJSP = "/table.jsp";
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(nextJSP);
    dispatcher.forward(request,response);
```

JSP:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
...
<c:forEach begin="0" end="${count}" varStatus="loop">
    Index: ${loop.index}<br/>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: I was trying that, but how do i implement it? Do i just put it in the servlet.java file as html code? Example: out.print("forEach code");

Comment: you need servlet and jsp both the files. Servlet is for server side logic and jsp for html rending.

Comment: Where would implement, <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %> I am using netbeans premade servlet.

Comment: It doesnt say to use anything but the index and servlet file in the assignment, that's the only way?.

Comment: you need to read about JSTL core tag library that provides some handy methods to use in jsp instead of Scriptlet (java code)

Comment: you need one html (form submission), servlet (to process the form data) and one jsp to show the result. HTML -> servlet -> JSP

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93126/discussion-between-renuz-and-braj).

Comment: posted complete example

Comment: it is giving me an error for RequestDispatcher in the servlet file.