# How to map a ResultSet with unknown amount of columns to a List and display it in a HTML table?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jdbc

I have created a Database Application using Netbeans, GlassFish and JavaDB. Now my controller Servlet code executes some dynamic SQL queries and get back a Result Set (or I can ahange toString). Now, how can I show the returned Result Set in a tabular format ( I have no idea about structure of result set). Can anybody help me about this ?

Comment: what problem are you having exactly? gettings the rows from the result set? generating a HTML table? show us the code you have and tell us where you're stuck.

Comment: @JB Nizet,  I have a code like, - createStatement(); resultset rs = st.executeQuery(sql query). Now I got stuck here. How to show this result set in a HTML table. As I have no idea about query, I have no idea about result set structure.

Comment: @ BalusC, I have seen your reffered page. But,to apply product.setId(resultSet.getLong("id")) - this I have to know how many colums and what table the statement is returnning. I have no idea of that.

Comment: I posted an answer. Note, to reply others in comments, please do not put a space after the `@`. I did not see your comment reply.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use [`Map<String, Object>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) to represent a "dynamic" row, which is [iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117557/how-to-iterate-an-arraylist-inside-a-hashmap-using-jstl) in `<c:forEach>`. You can use [`ResultSetMetaData`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) to collect information about the columns such as the [column count](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnCount%28%29) and the [column labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnLabel%28int%29).

So, this mapping should do:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> rows = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();

while (resultSet.next()) {
    Map<String, Object> columns = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();

    for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
        columns.put(metaData.getColumnLabel(i), resultSet.getObject(i));
    }

    rows.add(columns);
}
```

You can display it in JSP as follows:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <c:forEach items="${rows[0]}" var="column">
        <td><c:out value="${column.key}" /></td>
      </c:forEach>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <c:forEach items="${rows}" var="columns">
      <tr>
        <c:forEach items="${columns}" var="column">
          <td><c:out value="${column.value}" /></td>
        </c:forEach>
      </tr>
    </c:forEach>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks. However, in JSP page I can't see the result set. What I did is as follows: request.setAttribute("als",rows) in my servlet and in JSP, rows = session.getAttribute("als"); - Is anything missing ?

Comment: Just use `${als}`. Don't write Java code in JSP file. Your mistake is by the way that you tried to get it as a session attribtue instead of as a request attribute. Read on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-session-variables-and-multithreading

Comment: Sorry but I add Object rows = request.getAttribute("${als}"). however it showing rows variable not used. And problem remains same.

Comment: That's a warning, not an error. You seem to be not using the *scriptlet* variable anywhere at all. Just remove those nonsensicial *scriptlet* `<% ... %>` lines altogether and use `${als}` instead of `${rows}` as in `<c:forEach items="${als}">`, as said in previous comment (and please take some time to read the given links as well before you make more unnecessary mistakes in the future).

Answer (score 3):

Use the resultset metadata to know the number of columns returned by the query, the type of these columns, etc.

See [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html), which also has an example.