# How to fill the fields of a form from database when we call to the jsp page using JSTL and EL

Tags: jsp, jstl, el, form-fields

I have a jsp page which contains an html form. This form have a dropdown box which is filled with list of users. This list comes from database table. 
Previously I to fill this list I was using jsp scriptlets<%%> tag and in that tag I was writing the java code to get the list of users from database.
As I was introduced to jstl and el. I found it very easy. But my question is when I have a form like above; which contains some fields which will get
filled from database when we call the respective jsp page. How to use JSTL or EL to call the functions which will returns the list of users put it in to select box.

I am working on 
Apache Tomcat 6.0.X Which supports Servlet 2.5 and JSP 2.1
Java 1.6

Please guide me friends in this.
Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an SQL taglib: [reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/index.html).

But, doing that in the view is not recommended... call a servlet from your JSP instead.

JSTL/EL is supposed to be used only for the view layer.

Quote from the SO's JSTL wiki:

> Note that JSTL also offers SQL and XML taglibs which enable a
>   declarative manner of executing SQL queries and parsing XML inside a
>   JSP page. This is however discouraged for other purposes than quick
>   prototyping. In the real world both tasks need to be done by real Java
>   classes which are (in)directly controlled/delegated by a Servlet.

From your description, I would add the values to be displayed on the dropdown to the request (`request.setAttribute(...)`) from the servlet (obtaining them with a DAO class or an ORM framework), right before forwarding to this JSP.
Then you can iterate over the list of values with JSTL adding them as `<option>`s. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117557/how-to-iterate-an-arraylist-inside-a-hashmap-using-jstl) about how to iterate over a `List` or `Map` with JSTL.