# Iterate the Hashmap/ArrayList using JSTL

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, jstl

I have the following array:

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> array = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

[{name=BIRTH_DATE}, {catVal=07.11.2011}, {catStat=162}, {catVal=30.04.2011}, {catStat=108}, {CatVal=26.01.2011}]
```

I'd like to use JSTL  to choose between name, catVal and CatStat. I've tried the following, but it doesn't work. How can I get the key?

```
<table border="1">
<c:forEach items="${xml}" var="map">
    <tr>
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${map.key =='name'}">
                <td>${map.name}</td> 
            </c:when>
            <c:when test="${map.key == 'catVal'}">
                <td>${map.catVal}</td> 
            </c:when>
            <c:when test="${map.key == 'catStat'}">
                <td>${map.catStat}</td> 
            </c:when>
        </c:choose>

    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `${xml}` contains the `array` attribute of request/session:

- You're trying to read the entries of the `Map`s directly. You should start reading the elements from the list that are `Map`s.
- From [How to iterate an ArrayList inside a HashMap using JSTL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2117557/1065197), you're using the wrong syntax to access the current entry values of your map. You should use `entry.value` in your code:

  ```html
  <table border="1">
      <c:forEach items="${xml}" var="itemMap">
          <c:forEach items="${itemMap}" var="mapEntry">
          <tr>
              <td>
                  <c:choose>
                      <c:when test="${mapEntry.key == 'name'}">
                          <c:out value="Name:" />
                      </c:when>
                      <c:when test="${mapEntry.key == 'catVal'}">
                          <c:out value="Cat value:" />
                      </c:when>
                      <c:when test="${mapEntry.key == 'catStat'}">
                          <c:out value="Cat status:" /> 
                      </c:when>
                  </c:choose>
              </td>
              <td>
                  ${mapEntry.value}
              </td>
          </tr>
          </c:forEach>
      </c:forEach>
  </table>
  ```

Comment: Thank you for а comprehensive explanation!

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I also have similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22293665/how-to-show-multiple-tables-depending-on-key-in-the-map-using-jstl). See if you can help me out.. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @SSH I read it some hours ago and I upvoted the current posted answer because it solves your problem.