# How to show multiple tables depending on key in the Map using JSTL?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I have a Map of String and List of Object which contains each datacenter and its machine. And I am currently passing this object to JSP from my Controller and then I am iterating it in JSP page to show the data.

If the Map size is one, then I am able to show the data in a JSP page and it works fine.

Now suppose if the Map size is two, then I would like to show two tables one for each key in the map. This is what I am not able to make work. Maximum size of map can be 3 for my use case.

Below is my class which holds the data -

```
public class DatacenterMachineMapping {

    private Map<String, List<MachineMetrics>> datacenterMachines;

    // getters and setters
}

public class MachineMetrics {

    private String machineName;
    private String t2_95;
    private String t2_99;
    private String syncs;
    private String syncsBehind;
    private String average;

    // getters and setters
}
```

And below is my method in my Controller from which I need to pass an object to JSP and then iterate that object in JSP to show the data in a table -

```
@RequestMapping(value = "testOperation", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Map<String, String> testData() {

    final Map<String, String> model = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

    // for datacenter 1
    MachineMetrics metrics1 = new MachineMetrics();
    metrics1.setAvg("10");
    metrics1.setT2_95("100");
    metrics1.setT2_99("200");
    metrics1.setMachineName("machineA");
    metrics1.setSyncs("100");
    metrics1.setSyncsBehind("1000");

    MachineMetrics metrics2 = new MachineMetrics();
    metrics2.setAvg("20");
    metrics2.setT2_95("200");
    metrics2.setT2_99("300");
    metrics2.setMachineName("machineB");
    metrics2.setSyncs("200");
    metrics2.setSyncsBehind("2000");

    List<MachineMetrics> metricsA = new LinkedList<MachineMetrics>();
    metricsA.add(metrics1);
    metricsA.add(metrics2);

    // for datacenter 2
    MachineMetrics metrics3= new MachineMetrics();
    metrics3.setAvg("30");
    metrics3.setT2_95("300");
    metrics3.setT2_99("300");
    metrics3.setMachineName("machineC");
    metrics3.setSyncs("300");
    metrics3.setSyncsBehind("3000");

    MachineMetrics metrics4 = new MachineMetrics();
    metrics4.setAvg("40");
    metrics4.setT2_95("400");
    metrics4.setT2_99("400");
    metrics4.setMachineName("machineD");
    metrics4.setSyncs("400");
    metrics4.setSyncsBehind("4000");

    List<MachineMetrics> metricsB = new LinkedList<MachineMetrics>();
    metricsB.add(metrics3);
    metricsB.add(metrics4);     

    DatacenterMachineMapping mappings = new DatacenterMachineMapping();
    Map<String, List<MachineMetrics>> holder = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<MachineMetrics>>();
    holder.put("dc1", metricsA);
    holder.put("dc2", metricsB);

    mappings.setDatacenterMachines(holder);     

    model.put("testing", mappings); // passing this object to jsp

    return model;   
}
```

**Problem Statement:-**

As you can see in the above code, I have two keys as I have two datacenters one is `dc1` and other is `dc2`. So I would like to show two tables - one for `dc1` and its machines and second table for `dc2` and its machines as shown below.

So my data should look like this after iterating the `testing` object-

```
For DC1

Machine Name    T2_95   T2_99   Syncs   Syncs Behind    Average

machineA        100     200     100     1000            10
machineB        200     300     200     2000            20

For DC2

Machine Name    T2_95   T2_99   Syncs   Syncs Behind    Average

machineC        300     300     300     3000            30
machineD        400     400     400     4000            40
```

And below is my JSP page which works fine only for map size equal to one.. And I am not sure how to iterate the above `mappings` object in such a way in the JSP page so that I can show two tables for my above use case one for each key as shown above. Is this possible to do?

```
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Machine Name</th>
                <th>T2_95</th>
                <th>T2_99</th>
                <th>Syncs</th>
                <th>Syncs Behind</th>
                <th>Average</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        <c:set var="entry" value="${testing.datacenterMachines}"></c:set>
        <c:forEach var="m" items="${entry.value}">
           <tr>
              <td>${m.machineName}</td>
              <td>${m.t2_95}</td>
              <td>${m.t2_99}</td>
              <td>${m.syncs}</td>
              <td>${m.syncsBehind}</td>
              <td>${m.average}</td>
           </tr>
        </c:forEach>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

Any idea how can I make my JSP generic here? As it might be possible I can have three datacenters as currently I have two.

I am following up on my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22291238/how-to-iterate-a-list-in-a-map-of-string-and-list-of-object-using-jstl/22292556?noredirect=1#comment33869809_22292556) which helps me to iterate a map of size one but not sure how would I have two separate tables one for each key

**UPDATE:-**

This is what I have tried and it doesn't work for me -

```
<c:forEach var="e" items="${testing}">
  <h3>For <c:out value="${e.key}"/></h3>
    <table>
      <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Machine Name</th>
                <th>T2_95</th>
                <th>T2_99</th>
                <th>Syncs</th>
                <th>Syncs Behind</th>
                <th>Average</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <c:forEach var="m" items="${e.value}">
            <tr>
              <td>${m.machineName}</td>
              <td>${m.t2_95}</td>
              <td>${m.t2_99}</td>
              <td>${m.syncs}</td>
              <td>${m.syncsBehind}</td>
              <td>${m.average}</td>
             </tr>
           </c:ForEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</c:forEach>
```

And I am getting below exception and I am not sure what wrong I am doing here? -

```
Don't know how to iterate over supplied "items" in &lt;forEach&gt;
```

Comment: What's the name of the request attribute that holds your `Map`?

Comment: This is what I have in my above code - `model.put("testing", mappings);` And I am using `testing` in my JSP.

Comment: Looks like you have another request (or session or application or page context) attribute with the same name. Can you try again using a different name for your request attribute? Because AFAICS in your code, it should work.

Comment: With what name? You saying for `testing` I have some other name with that as well?

Comment: Yes... That's what I'm saying. Try using a different more unique name for the test.

Comment: Yes. I just tried that and same error I got -  `Don't know how to iterate over supplied "items" in &lt;forEach&gt;`. There is something else going on.

Comment: Got that working.. We need to use `testing.datacenterMachines` instead of using testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
<c:forEach var="e" items="${entry}">
  <h3>For <c:out value="${e.key}"/></h3>
    <table>
      <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Machine Name</th>
                <th>T2_95</th>
                <th>T2_99</th>
                <th>Syncs</th>
                <th>Syncs Behind</th>
                <th>Average</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <c:forEach var="m" items="${e.value}">
            <tr>
              <td>${m.machineName}</td>
              <td>${m.t2_95}</td>
              <td>${m.t2_99}</td>
              <td>${m.syncs}</td>
              <td>${m.syncsBehind}</td>
              <td>${m.average}</td>
             </tr>
           <c:ForEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: I think there is something missing `c:forEach var="m" value="${e.value}">` it should be `c:forEach var="m" items="${e.value}">` Btw, your code is useful for me :) Thanks you :)

Comment: @ArkLinlin thanks for pointing out the issue with the code i have updated the answer accordingly.