# <c:forEach> usage

Tags: jsp, servlets, jstl, el

I'm trying to display images from my database. It works fine when I want to display
my own image using ......`<b>Image:</b> <img src="images/uploads/${user.getImage()}"`
However if I want to display a different user or all users image a blank square appears. I think it may have to do with the `<c:forEach>` tag but unsure.

```
 <c:forEach var="user" items="${UserList}">
      <p><br><b>Name :</b></p> ${user.getUsername()}<a href="ProfilePage2.jsp">View Profile Page</a>
      <div id="img2"><b>Image:</b> <img src="images/uploads/${user.getImage()}"  width="200px" height="150px"/></div>
 </c:forEach>
```

The name displays fine but not the image! Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please refer to [How to iterate an Arraylist inside a HashMap using jstl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2117557/1065197) to understand the problems in this code.

Comment: By the way, which type is `user.image`?

Comment: the type is varchar...thanks!

Comment: Looks like the problem is that the images don't exist in your */images/uploads/* folder.

Comment: Check html source code, is the correct path generated for the image?

Answer (score 1):

What does the User.getImage() method return?

Also, Try:

```
<img src="images/uploads/${user.image}"  width="200px" height="150px"/>
```