# Java/JSP iteration with/without bean

Tags: java, jsp, iterator, javabeans

I have a quick question on iterating over an array list from a class file onto jsp file.

### Snippet from a class file:

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
public ArrayList getStatus() {
   Object o;
   this.Status = al;  //contents of the array list  
   return Status;
}
```

### Below is a snippet from the jsp file:

```
<jsp:useBean id="mybean" class="org.mypackage.process" scope="session" >



<jsp:setProperty name="mybean" property="input" value="hello" />



</jsp:useBean>



<jsp:getProperty name="mybean" property="status" />
```

When I run above, I get the arraylist as a bunch of string separated by commas. I need help in generating a table with the output from the array list. Can the array list be generated using forEach so that I can create tables.

I am not using any frameworks. I can run jstl tags on jsp.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `forEach` loop of **JSTL**. You can check the [SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117557/how-to-iterate-an-arraylist-inside-a-hashmap-using-jstl) as well.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>

<table>
  <th>Header1</th>
  <th>Header2</th>
  <c:forEach items="${mybean.status}" var="element">
    <tr>
      <td><c:out value="${element.attribute1}" /><td>
      <td><c:out value="${element.attribute2}" /><td>
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Noob. It worked. 

 <c:forEach items="${mybean.status}" var="element">
    <tr>
      <td><c:out value="${element}" /><td>
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>

Comment: Noob - Can you please elaborate on the attributes?  Can you please include an example on how I can create an array list containing multiple columns(attribute1,attribute2, etc) on the class file to display on a jsp file?