# How to upload List object into Model in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, model-view-controller, spring-mvc

So, I've got the following method in the Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/modules.htm",method = RequestMethod.GET )
protected String modules(ModelMap model) throws Exception {

      List<Module> modules = moduleService.getStudentModules(course_id);
      model.addAttribute....?
      return "modules";
}
```

And I need to display this list in jsp View, like:

```
<h1>Modules: </h1>
module 1 
module 2... etc
```

What do I need to add to show the full list on the JSP page? How should I upload it to the model and retrieve it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `model.addAttribute("modules", modules);` will add the list to the model. Use [`jstl`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117557/how-to-iterate-an-arraylist-inside-a-hashmap-using-jstl) to loop over the list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pass the whole list:

```java
model.addAttribute("modules", modules);
```

Then iterate on it:

```xml
<c:forEach items="${modules}" var="module">
    ${module.anyProperty}
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: ".anyProperty" - would that refer to the method declared in the object? i.e. ".getModuleName()" (I'm not very familiar with views code :P )

Comment: @exomen It refers to any getter of the class, but *without the `get` part*. For example, to call `.getModuleName()`, you'll have to write `.moduleName`. This is called *Expression Language*, have a look at the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html) for further info.

Comment: what if in class it is private?

Comment: @exomen I never tried actually, but I guess it won't work since a getter can't be private by definition. Moreover, it has no functional meaning, a private method shouldn't be called from somewhere else than in the class itself.

Comment: nope, I mean getter is public, but the field is private and when you call smth like ".code" in theory it must return field, not the result of get() method.. isn't it? :P

Comment: @exomen No, that's what I told you (you should really read the doc `:)`). Let's say your class `Module` has a private field `name` and a public getter `getName()`. In your JSP files, when calling `.name`, the getter will be called, and not the field itself. With `.name`, the compiler will look for a method called `getName()` (or `isName()`, essentially used for booleans). Even if you have a private field `name` but no corresponding getter, an exception will be thrown.