# JSF 2.0 Iterate over a Map of Collection

Tags: jsf, jstl

I am new to this community. I am using JSF 2.0 having web-app version as 2.5. I am running the application in tomcat 6 server.

I want to show the messages stored in the string property messageDesc present in the bean UserMessageBean.java. My data structure is

`Map(Integer, List(UserMessageBean))`.

I am unable to iterate over the map to show the messages.

I am trying to use c:foreach to display the message string but I failed to do so.

Thanks for your support in advance.

Comment: Some code would definitely help.

Comment: The map is declared as Map(Integer, List(UserMessageBean)) = new HashMap(Integer, List(UserMessageBean)). I am populating the map by userMessageMap.put(userMessages.getId(), userMessageBeans); Here userMessagesBeans is the list of UserMessageBean object. Not sure what will be the exact syntax in the xhtml file to show the message string which is a property of UserMessageBean object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to iterate an Arraylist inside a HashMap using jstl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117557/how-to-iterate-an-arraylist-inside-a-hashmap-using-jstl)

Comment: AFAIK in Java you declare a `Map` as `Map<Integer, List<UserMessageBean>> someVariableName = new HashMap<Integer, List<UserMessageBean>>();`. Please post real code instead of pseudocode for this kind of questions.

Comment: Sorry Luiggi, I was trying to give the actual code but code after the < tag was not considered. I am new to this forum so don't know the exact syntax to provide code. I was trying to post Map<Integer, List<UserMessageBean>> userMessageMap = new HashMap<Integer, List<UserMessageBean>>();

Comment: Thanks Luiggi for the link. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Don't worry about the code, just post it. Some people would edit your question content and properly format the code, so then you could learn how to format it by yourself.

Comment: I followed the above post and I am trying to display the text in JSF 2.0 in the following way. But it is coming as blank:
 `<ui:define name="title">Login</ui:define>
 <ui:define name="content">
  <h:form>
    <c:forEach items="${loginBean.userMessagesMap}" var="entry">
      <h:outputText id="msgId" value="#{entry.key}" />
        <c:forEach items="${entry.value}" var="item" varStatus="loop">
          <h:outputText id="msgDesc" value="#{item.messageDesc}" />
        </c:forEach>
      </c:forEach>
  </h:form>
 </ui:define>
</ui:composition>` What I am missing here?

Comment: Thanks @Luiggi for the link and BalusC for sharing the information. I am able to bring the texts. This forum rocks..