# Get Value using key from Map not working in JSP

Tags: jsp, dictionary, enums, key-value

I have the following code: detailsMap is map of LinkedHashMap type. I am able to get the value  ${roleType} as L1, correctly printing the value of ${detailsMap["L1"]} but not ${detailsMap[roleType]}. Please suggest what I am doing wrong. roleTypes are enum values.

```
<c:set var="detailsMap" value="${hostDetails.value}" />
    <c:forEach items="${roleTypes}" var="roleType">
    <td>${detailsMap[roleType]}</td>
    <td>${detailsMap["L1"]}</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="${roleType}" value="" /></td>
    </c:forEach>
    </tr>
    </c:forEach>
```

---

I made it working by setting the attribute as String List in place of enum Values.

Answer (score 1):

I would have expected that to work.  I have some code here where I do something like this:

```
<c:set var="roleType" value="${someOtherVariable}" scope="page"/>
<li class="${cssMap[roleType]}"/>
```

And that works. Does the iteration variable need to be placed in page scope for some reason?

Comment: I need iteration variable only for this iteration. But I am able to get correct value of roleType at <td><input type="text" name="${roleType}" value="" /></td>.

Answer (score 1):

If `roleType` is an `enum`, you should use `.name()` method when you use it as a key of a `map`:

```
<td>${detailsMap[roleType.name()]}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood very well the question, but from what I understood this part  :

```
<c:forEach items="${roleTypes}" var="roleType">
<td>${detailsMap[roleType]}</td>
```

Should be replaced with something like this :

```
<c:forEach items="${roleTypes}" var="roleType">
<td>${detailsMap[${roleType}]}</td>
```

The explanation is that `roleType` is not a string, but an iterator, what you want is the value of the iterator, therefore you need the `${}`.

Coudn't test this, but it's what I thought might be a problem.

**Related** : [How to iterate an Arraylist inside a HashMap using jstl ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117557/how-to-iterate-an-arraylist-inside-a-hashmap-using-jstl).

Best of luck.

Comment: Hum... Is it necessary to iterate over that `enum` ?

Comment: Now, I am passing the String List not enum values then, its working. Thank you for help.
${detailsMap[${roleType}]} expression gives an error. Although I am ble to use ${detailsMap[roleType]} with String list.

Comment: so you made `roleType` a string list ? nice idea.

Comment: Yes, just before setting the attribute, I converted it into a String List.

Comment: Would be nice if you could post the answer for futur generations, this type of posts may be of use for many new developers to come :)