# how to access the elements of an arraylist which is inside another arraylist passed to jsp from servlet?

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

I have an arraylist(which itself stores 6 arraylists ) in my servlet class. I am passing this arraylist to a jsp where I want to access the elements which are stored in the inner arraylists individually. I am able to iterate the outer arraylist but when I try to iterate the inner arraylists, I am not able to do it.....please help.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use two nested JSTL `forEach` elements.

Comment: Hi Sotirios, thanks for the reply but can u please give an example code....as I am new to jstl....I was using scriplets in jsp. I know its noy good but I have a loose jand on jstl...plz help..

Comment: [Here are a bunch of examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117557/how-to-iterate-an-arraylist-inside-a-hashmap-using-jstl). Modify them to fit the requirement of nested `ArrayList` objects.

Answer (score -2):

try like this, will help you:

```
 for(ArrayList<myFirstType> list1: frstList){
     for(ArrayList<mySecondType> list2: list1){
             print-> list2   
       }
    }
```

Comment: If you're going to provide code, make it compile. And put it in context. Is this meant to be a scriptlet?