# How to show elements of a SET in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I am dealing with a legacy system that has track of all past exams and the topics that has been covered in each.

For example:

```
Exam1 1/1/1980
topicID topicName topicRFCode  Description
1         AAA         1         fdfdfgfdgdf
1         AAA         2         cvcvcvcvcv
20        XXX         1         asasasasas
12        MMM         3         klklklkl
12        MMM         1         erererer
12        MMM         2         jkjkjkjkjkjk
```

As you can see, three different topics were covered in 1/1/1980 exam.
Two questions were related to topic AAA
One question was related to topic XXX and
three questions were related to topic MMM.

Java passes a list of topics that are related to the selected exam to JSP then I try to show descriptions of each topic separately, I have following

```
       <c:forEach var="topic" items="${topics}" >
            <c:if test="${topic.topicId == '1'}">
                <c:forEach var="aaa" items="${topics}">
                        <c:if test="${aaa.topicId == '1'}">
                            <p>${aaa.description}</p>
                        </c:if>
                </c:forEach>
            </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

The problems are:

- Current code has two for loops so for each topic I should have a
  separate pair of codes as I want to show all descriptions for each
  topic one after another.
- Because of multiple for loops it is quite slow.
- Not sure if this is the best approach to the issue.

Comment: Whats the issue? whats the down vote for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing list, you can pass Map of List of `Topic`.

```
Map<String, List<Topic>> // Key as topicID
```

For how to iterate Map, you can refer this [`answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2117678/3898076) by @BalusC.

Comment: Cool, then how to iterate through it? how does this help?

Comment: You can iterate Map and print its inside list content.