# How to iterate over a nested map in <c:forEach>

Tags: jsp, foreach, hashmap, jstl

I've a `Map` in a bean as follows:

```
public class TaskListData {
    private Map<String, String[]> srcMasks = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
    private Map<Integer, Map<String, String[]>> ftqSet = new HashMap<Integer, Map<String, String[]>>();

    public void setFTQSet(Integer ftqid, String[] src, String[] masks) {  
        srcMasks.put("srcDir", src);
        srcMasks.put("masks", masks);
        ftqSet.put(ftqid, srcMasks);
    }
```

This `ftqSet` fits in below datastructure:

```
feedId = "5",
feedName = "myFeedName",
ftqSet => {
            1 => {
                    srcDirs = ["/path/string"],
                    masks = ["p.txt", "q.csv"]
                 }
            2 => { ...
                 }
          }, ...
```

In my test JSP file I've been trying to access the data using `<c:forEach>`:

```
<c:forEach items="#{bean.ftqSet}" var="f">
    this text does not print
    ${f.feedId}
</c:forEach>
```

But it's not outputting `${f.feedId}`. Why would this be? How would I access this structure's individual elements so I can create a nice table?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Each iteration of `Map` in a `c:forEach` gives a [`Map.Entry`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) instance which in turn has [`getKey()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#getKey%28%29) and [`getValue()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#getValue%28%29) methods. It's similar to doing `for (Entry entry : map.entrySet())` in plain Java.

E.g.

```
<c:forEach items="#{bean.map}" var="entry">
    <h:outputText value="Key: #{entry.key}, Value: #{entry.value}" /><br />
</c:forEach>
```

In case of a `Map<Integer, Map<String, String[]>>` the `#{entry.value}` returns a `Map<String, String[]>`, so you need to iterate over it as well:

```
<c:forEach items="#{bean.map}" var="entry">
    <h:outputText value="Key: #{entry.key}, Values:" />
    <c:forEach items="#{entry.value}" var="nestedentry">
        <h:outputText value="Nested Key: #{nestedentry.key}, Nested Value: #{nestedentry.value}" />
    </c:forEach><br />
</c:forEach>
```

But in your case, the `#{nestedentry.value}` is actually a `String[]`, so we need to iterate over it again:

```
<c:forEach items="#{bean.map}" var="entry">
    <h:outputText value="Key: #{entry.key}, Values:" />
    <c:forEach items="#{entry.value}" var="nestedentry">
        <h:outputText value="Nested Key: #{nestedentry.key}, Nested Values: " />
        <c:forEach items="#{nestedentry.value}" var="nestednestedentry">
            <h:outputText value="#{nestednestedentry}" />
        </c:forEach><br />
    </c:forEach><br />
</c:forEach>
```

By the way, this ought to work with `rich:dataList` as well.