# Accessing java-based DOM tree directly from JSF/richfaces

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, richfaces, jstl

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141464/how-to-access-complex-java-maps-in-jsf-richfaces) I have a couple of other questions:

1) the map in this question which is made available to jsf is actually one of a number, so i'm now not sure what the backing bean method's return type should now be.  if i modify it's current `Array<String>` return type to `Array<Map Integer, Map<String, String[]>>>` (or `ArrayList<Map Integer, Map<String, String[]>>>` ?) would it just be a case of further nesting the iterator on the jsf side?  Trouble is an Array/ArrayList isn't a Map and I'm unsure how this then looks in jsf. would this be correct:

```
<c:forEach items="#{bean.map}" var="entry">                     <!-- array -->
  <c:forEach items="#{entry.value}" var="nentry">               <!-- map -->
    <h:outputText value="Key: #{nentry.key}, Values:" />        <!-- integer -->
    <c:forEach items="#{nentry.value}" var="nnentry">           <!-- sub map -->
      <h:outputText value="Key: #{nnentry.key}, Values:" />     <!-- string -->
      <c:forEach items="#{nnentry.value}" var="nnnentry">       <!-- string[] -->
        <h:outputText value="#{nnnentry}" />
      </c:forEach><br />
    </c:forEach><br />
  </c:forEach><br />
</c:forEach>
```

?

2) what i'm really storing in this map is xpath rips from an XML DOM tree parsed on the java side.  i'm now thinking i can access this java-based DOM tree from JSF directly without having to use XPath -> ArrayOfMaps and return that.  In an XML file which looks something like this, is there a better way than using the above  method?:

```
 <test>                                              
  <testid>1</testid>                          
  <testname>myName</testname>

  <inst>                                      
   <id>1</id>                  
   <src>C:\my\path</src>               
   <mask>.*\.\w{3}</mask>      
   <mask>.*\.x</mask>          
  </inst>

  <inst>                                      
   <id>2</id>                  
   <src>C:\my\otherpath</src>               
   <mask>.*\.\w{3}</mask>      
   <mask>.*\.x</mask>          
  </inst>
</test>
```

Thanks again
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> <c:forEach items="#{bean.map}" var="entry">                     <!-- array -->
>   <c:forEach items="#{entry.value}" var="nentry">               <!-- map -->
> ```

This is wrong. Each iteration over an `ArrayList` doesn't return a `Map.Entry` object at all as you seem to think. It just returns the individual element of the `List` (which is in your case a `Map`). Here's how it should look like:

```
<c:forEach items="#{bean.list}" var="map">                        <!-- array -->
  <c:forEach items="#{map}" var="entry">                          <!-- map -->
```

In nutshell, a `c:forEach` iteration over an `List` or `Object[]` as follows

```
<c:forEach items="${array}" var="item">
    ...
</c:forEach>
```

is best to be interpreted in raw Java code as

```
for (Object item : array) {
    // ...
}
```

while a `c:forEach` iteration over `Map` as demonstrated in your [previous topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141464/how-to-access-complex-java-maps-in-jsf-richfaces/2141513#2141513) is best to be interpreted in raw Java code as:

```
for (Entry<K, V> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    K key = entry.getKey();       // ${entry.key}
    V value = entry.getValue();   // ${entry.value}
}
```

Comment: are # and $ interchangeable in object references as above?

Comment: Yes. The `#` and `$` can do both a `get`, but only the `#` can do a `set` as well. So if you use for example `${managedbeanname}`, it won't create managed bean if it isn't already created yet (and thus it will potentially return null). The `#{managedbeanname}` instead will create bean if not done yet.

Comment: Still learning from you BalusC, didn't know about the # and $

Comment: @Triztian: you're welcome. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812755/difference-between-jsp-el-jsf-el-and-unified-el for a bit of history.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://blog.boyandi.net/2007/11/21/jsp-recursion/) show a way to use recursion with JSTL. You can give it a try:

```
<c:forEach var="node" items="${node.children}">
    <c:set var="node" value="${node}" scope="request"/>
    <jsp:include page="node.jsp"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Just, in order to accommodate your case, you can put the following *before* the loop:

```
<c:set var="node" value="#{backingBean.rootNode}" />
```

Comment: Are you suggesting that node is my backing bean class reference?

Comment: no. before that you can have `<c:set var="node" value="#{backingBean.rootNode}"`