# JSF and EJB #{...} not allowed in a template text body

Tags: templates, jsf, datagrid, ejb

I've added 2 managed beans:
ProductController with 2 method:

```
ist<ProdusDTO> getList()
String update()
```

and ProductDTO, for entity Product.

index.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="f"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="h"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>
<h:dataTable value="#{ProductController.getList()}" var="p">
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Description</f:facet> #{p.description}
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Image</f:facet> #{p.image}
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>

    <h2>Adds</h2>
    <h:form>
        <h:panelGrid columns="3">
            Description: <h:inputText value="#{produsDTO.description}" size="100" required="true"></h:inputText>
            Image: <h:inputText value="#{productDTO.image}" size="100" required="true" label="Image"> </h:inputText>
        </h:panelGrid>
        <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{ProductController.update()}" />
    </h:form>
```

When I run the jsp file, I get this error:

```
PWC6228: #{...} not allowed in a template text body.
```

In the build path I've included jsf-api.jar and jsf-impl.jar (mojjara 1.2_15)

Why I can't specify for a dataTable component a method for value attribute?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unified expression language [deferred expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7209377/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-el-syntax) are only allowed in custom tag attributes that support them (see [JSP 2.1](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=245) for UEL support).

This is a limitation of using JSPs and JSF. Deferred expressions must be used with a control tag (e.g. an [outputText](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/1.2_MR1/docs/tlddocs/h/outputText.html).)

*This issue was addressed with the Facelets view technology; consider upgrading if this is possible.*

Comment: After replacing # with $, I've get another error: According to the TLD, the attribute value is a deferred-value or deferred-method, but the specified value contains a $-expression

Comment: @Emanuel - `${}` and `#{}` expressions are evaluated at different times using different mechanisms. You can only use deferred expressions within a `dataTable`.

Comment: He has already answered it: use for example an `<h:outputText>` *(or just get rid of JSP and upgrade to its successor Facelets)*