# JSTL <c:if test> without contains

Tags: java, javascript, xhtml

Good Morning. It is the first time I have decided to ask a question .

I 'm working on a xhtml and want to put this condition:

```
<c:if test="#{fichaTecnicaBean.seccionesSeleccionadas.contains("text")}">
```

to include or not a `<div>` on display , but does not work for the contains . I tried it with javascript but neither I also enters the function:

```
<c:if test="javascript:find('text');">
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

JSTL tags are evaluated on server side, so `javascript` which is executed on client side can't works inside `<c:if>` test attribute.

Try using `$` instead of `#` which I think fits better your case (For more info about the difference of `$` and `#` see the answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8791328/what-are-the-differences-between-and)).

Also in some jsp/servlet old versions invoke methods not work on JSTL and you can only work with the object properties (this is probably why`.contains()` not work). So since `fichaTecnicaBean.seccionesSeleccionadas` is a `List<String>` you can try using `<c:forEach>` and comparing their elements as follows:

```
<c:forEach items="${fichaTecnicaBean.seccionesSeleccionadas}" var="seccion"> 
    <c:if test ="${seccion == 'text'} ">
    ...
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks for the help , I have not solved my problem because I get error <% @ taglib ...% > . The tomcat shows me the following error:

javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing /views/fichaTecnica/listaComponentes.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 18] El contenido de los elementos debe constar de marcadores o datos de carácter con un formato correcto.
 at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doCompile

I tried to put them at first too but does not recognize me <%@taglib

 I see the contains method seeking a strng in another string and I search for a string in a List < String>

Comment: @IgnacioUnzueta oh, I don't know that you're working with a list, I think that now my answer it's more accurate `:)`