# struts2 s:url with s:property value not working

Tags: java, struts2

I am trying to use `s:url` and the value contains a property. And it's not working.

```
<s:url value='/js/myJS-<s:property value="locale"/>.js'/>
```

Expected output:

```
....../contextPath/js/myJS-en_US.js
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nesting JSP tags like that is illegal.

Use normal JSP EL (assuming you're on a container supporting it):

```
<s:url value="/js/myJS-${locale}.js"/>
```

If you're not running a container that supports JSP EL (ew), use OGNL:

```
<s:url value="/js/myJS-%{locale}.js"/>
```

It's arguable this is the preferred mechanism since OGNL is S2's default EL.

---

When reporting something as "not working", you should also include what error(s) you get, for example, in this case, the JSP would never compile.

Comment: Sorry, I am quite new to struts2.
I have just try your code and the locale is not evaluated. What should I do/include to support EL in my jsp?

Comment: @Drogba As long as you're using any recent servlet container and have the web.xml set to 2.5+ (IIRC) it should work w/o any issues.

Comment: the web.xml version is 2.4. Any alternative?

Comment: @Drogba Switch to 2.5. It's a container issue, not a web.xml issue. Or use OGNL, S2's native EL: `<s:url value="/js/myJS-%{locale}.js"/>`, which might be the preferable solution anyway.

Comment: Thanks so much. it works like a charm. 
You have mentioned that container issue, i am a bit confused about this. The difference between "%" and "$" is related to jboss? web.xml? struts lib? tag? Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: @Drogba http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421567/whats-the-difference-between-and/9421667#9421667