# Some Error in Expression Language Configuration <jsp-config>

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

One EL config issue is there:

```jsp
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
${10 + 15}<br>
```

While using the above statements I am getting the perfect output i.e. 25. Now I want to `isELIgnored="false"` for the entire web application so I modified the web.xml as:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>
    <jsp-config>
        <jsp-property-group>
            <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
            <el-ignored>false</el-ignored>
        </jsp-property-group>
    </jsp-config>
</web-app>
```

But not getting the proper output. What is wrong over there? Some additional steps are required or what? Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is _the proper output_?

Comment: EL is not ignored by default. You don't need to configure anything.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis the output should be 25 but its ${10 + 15}

Comment: @JBNizet I tried that as well. In every case I am getting ${10 + 15}, which should be 25

Comment: What JSP version are you using?

Comment: @shashanksoni post your `web.xml` also

Comment: @ankur-singhal: <web-app>

 <jsp-config>
  <jsp-property-group>
   <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
   <el-ignored>false</el-ignored>
  </jsp-property-group>
 </jsp-config>

</web-app>

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis its 2.0

Comment: @shashanksoni does this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9676636/jstl-variables-are-not-shown-in-el) help you

Comment: @shashanksoni i want your complete `web.xml` including `<?xml version=`

Comment: @ankur-singhal i updated in question itselsef just now, plz take a look

Comment: @shashanksoni i posted answer, does it help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `web.xml` to a version that supports `EL (2.5+ XSD)`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     version="2.5">

</web-app>
```

or whichever version

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
          version="3.0">

  </web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

ankur-singhals answer worked for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:web="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <jsp-config>
        <jsp-property-group>
           <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
           <el-ignored>false</el-ignored>
        </jsp-property-group>
    </jsp-config>
</web-app>
```