# Map being read but not set by HtmlInputText

Tags: jsf-2

I have a dynamically created `HtmlInputText`, which is set to pull its value from a map in a session scoped bean. Like so.

```
HtmlInputText input = new HtmlInputText();
String expression = "${catalogue.itemValues.A" + item.getId() + "}";
ValueExpression valExpression = expressionFactory.createValueExpression(facesInstance.getELContext(), expression, String.class);
input.setValueExpression("value",valExpression);
```

where `itemValues` is a map with a getter of `getItemValues()` and the key would be `A1`, `A2`, etc.

I have programatically added a value to the `Map` with the key `A1` and value `1234`.  Whenever the JSF page appears, the value is rendered. However, when I change the value and submit the form, the value is not changed.

I have tested with a `h:inputText` element and linked it to the same key and it is able to update the value and the new value is reflected in the generated `HtmlInputText` component.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `#{}` syntax to bind input values, not the `${}` syntax. The `#{}` can do a `get` and `set`, while the `${}` can only do a `get`.

#### See also:

- [Difference between JSP EL, JSF EL and Unified EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812755/difference-between-jsp-el-jsf-el-and-unified-el)

Comment: Then you've another problem in the code which is not visible in the code posted so far. Perhaps the way how you're creating/manipulating/storing components is plain wrong? To the point, this job should **not** be done in a getter method and **every** manually created `UIInput`/`UICommand` component must have an unique fixed ID set by `setId()`. Those two are at least the most common beginner's mistakes.

Comment: @BalusC Thanks, for me it was that I forgot to add the unique fixed Id to the inputText.