# C for each of jsf is not working . JSF

Tags: java, jsf, jstl

i am trying to use **c foreach with hashmap or table in jsf 2.0** but it is not working so i wrote one simple code like this still this one is not working .... please help where i am missing...

```
<body>
<f:view>
    <c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="20" step="1" varStatus ="status">
        <c:out value="#{i}" /> 
    </c:forEach>
</f:view>
```

and output for this i am getting like this ..

```
#{i} #{i} #{i} #{i} #{i} #{i} #{i} #{i} #{i} #{i} #{i} #{i} #{i} #{i} #{i} #{i} #{i} #{i} #{i} #{i}
```

Comment: <c:foreach> is not JSF but JSTL. Try using <ui:repeat>

Comment: Since the looping is obviously working (hence the number of #{i} in the output) it must be the c:out that isn't.

Comment: hey it is not working ... even if i replaced with # ....  it is having some problem ..

Comment: NO solution for my problem ??? where i am making mistake ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$` instead of `#`

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="20" step="1" varStatus ="status">
        <c:out value="${i}" /> 
</c:forEach>
```

`<c:forEach>` is from JSTL, with JSF you should use `<ui:repeat>` as *Luiggi* commented

Comment: hey it is not working ... even if i replaced with # .... it is having some problem .. can u please tell me whether i should use xhtml template or something to make it work ... i tried all thing but it is not working ...

Comment: i am getting one error like " According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute value does not accept any expressions
"..

Comment: after rending in browser it is displaying like this<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core">

<head>
<title>JSTL Simple Conditional Execution Example</title>
</head><body>
        <c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="20" step="1" varStatus="status">
     <c:out value=""></c:out> 
    </c:forEach></body>
</html>

Answer (score 6):

EL will fail in JSTL tags in a JSF2 webapp when you're using the ancient and EOL'ed JSTL 1.0 for some reason.

Make sure that you've installed at least JSTL 1.1 or 1.2. JSTL 1.2 is recommended. First remove `jstl.jar` **and** `standard.jar` from your `/WEB-INF/lib`, then download [`jstl-1.2.jar`](http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar) and drop it in `/WEB-INF/lib`. Finally make sure that you set the XML namespace as follows (with the `/jsp` path in the URI!):

```
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
```

#### See also:

- [Our JSTL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)
- [Difference between JSP EL, JSF EL and Unified EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812755/difference-between-jsp-el-jsf-el-and-unified-el)

Answer (score 1):

you are not specifying what exactly does not work when you use it with your map... did you try setting the items of your map/table within the foreach:

```
<c:forEach items="#{myMap}" var="item">             
  <h:outputText value="#{item.key}" />
  <h:outputText value="#{item.value}" />
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: i used the same thing to print key and value pair but is not displaying any thing ... i am using .xhtml template. in page source i found that code is not rending properly in browser .. it is displaying block of code simply..

Comment: yes .. others are working fine like "graphicimage" and "outputtext" all are working fine ..

Comment: what about other jstl tags like <c:if> or sth. like that?

Comment: hey i am adding what is HTML output ..<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core">

<head>
<title>JSTL Simple Conditional Execution Example</title>
</head><body>
   <c:forEach var="nameMap" items="{Versnellingsk=A very long text come here, Kleur=ZWART Two, Model=3008, Carrosiere=5 deures MPV, A very long text come here=Date Here, BrandShoert=E, Type=3008 Hybrid4 2.0 HDi, Merk=Peugeot, Bowjaar=2011 Shortgate}">
      <p> </p>
 </c:forEach></body>
</html>

Comment: i think it is not rendering properly..what i have to for that .. i am using .xhtml Extesion ?? whether it is wrong ??

Comment: My code sample is this : 
<html xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<head>
<title>JSTL Simple Conditional Execution Example</title>
</head>
 <h:body>
  <f:view>
   <c:forEach var="nameMap" items="${specificationAutogege.details}">
      <p> ${nameMap.key}</p>
 </c:forEach>
   </f:view>
 </h:body>
</html>