# Dynamic JSF (2.0) commandButtons - set action with arguments

Tags: jsf, dynamic, jsf-2, action

I'm trying to add JSF `<h:commandButtons>` dynamically to my webpage, and so far I have them displaying, but I cannot set the action with parameters, like I could in a static page:
`action="#{bean.function(parameter)}"`.  (this is of course using EL-2.2)
 Looking around I find that I have to create a `MethodExpression`, but this is obscure to me and I haven't been able to find much information on this. If someone could shine a light through the fog and explain how this can be done, it would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: so now I have this

```
public void displayNode( String childName ){
//lots of messy code instantiating JSF components

if( activeEmployee.getParent() != null ){
        HtmlCommandButton parent = new HtmlCommandButton();
        HtmlOutputText parentLabel = new HtmlOutputText();

        parentLabel.setId("label" + count++);  //I really hate having to use count
        parentLabel.setValue( "Parent: " );

        parent.setId("Parent" + count++); 
        String parentName = activeEmployee.getParent().getName();
        parent.setValue( parentName );
        MethodExpression expression = createMethodExpression("#{tree.displayNode('" + parentName + "')}",
                                                                null, String.class);
        parent.setActionExpression( expression );

        newDiv.getChildren().add( parentLabel );
        newDiv.getChildren().add( parent );
    }
```

Comment: Can you not use the rendered property to show/hide the command button?

Comment: nah I'm dynamically creating tree nodes with buttons to display other related nodes

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [`ExpressionFactory#createMethodExpression()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/el/ExpressionFactory.html#createMethodExpression%28javax.el.ELContext,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Class%5B%5D%29).

> ```
> public abstract MethodExpression createMethodExpression(
>                                       ELContext context,
>                                       java.lang.String expression,
>                                       java.lang.Class<?> expectedReturnType,
>                                       java.lang.Class<?>[] expectedParamTypes)
> ```

Here's a convenience method:

```
public static MethodExpression createMethodExpression(String expression, Class<?> returnType, Class<?>... parameterTypes) {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    return facesContext.getApplication().getExpressionFactory().createMethodExpression(
        facesContext.getELContext(), expression, returnType, parameterTypes);
}
```

The following action method examples:

```
public void submit1()
public String submit2()
public void submit3(String argument)
public String submit4(String argument)
public void submit5(String argument1, Long argument2)
public String submit6(Long argument1, String argument2)
```

can then be created as follows:

```
createMethodExpression("#{bean.submit1}", null);
createMethodExpression("#{bean.submit2}", String.class);
createMethodExpression("#{bean.submit3('foo')}", null, String.class);
createMethodExpression("#{bean.submit4('foo')}", String.class, String.class);
createMethodExpression("#{bean.submit5('foo', 0)}", null, String.class, Long.class);
createMethodExpression("#{bean.submit6(0, 'foo')}", String.class, Long.class, String.class);
```

Note that the EL expression is exactly the same as you would use in the normal view file.

---

**Update** here's an SSCCE which works fine for me with Mojarra 2.1.12 on Tomcat 7.0.27.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
>
    <h:head>
        <title>SO question 12098611</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form binding="#{bean.form}">
            <h:commandButton value="add" action="#{bean.add}" />
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

```java
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Bean {

    private UIForm form;

    public void add() {
        String id = "button" + form.getChildCount();
        UICommand button = new HtmlCommandButton();
        button.setId(id);
        button.setValue(id);
        button.setActionExpression(createMethodExpression(String.format("#{bean.submit('%s')}", id), null, String.class));
        form.getChildren().add(button);
    }

    public void submit(String arg) {
        System.out.println("submit: " + arg);
    }

    public UIForm getForm() {
        return form;
    }

    public void setForm(UIForm form) {
        this.form = form;
    }

    public static MethodExpression createMethodExpression(String expression, Class<?> returnType, Class<?>... parameterTypes) {
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        return facesContext.getApplication().getExpressionFactory().createMethodExpression(
            facesContext.getELContext(), expression, returnType, parameterTypes);
    }

}
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, all of above is a poor practice. See also [How does the 'binding' attribute work in JSF? When and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911158/how-does-the-binding-attribute-work-in-jsf-when-and-how-should-it-be-used)

Comment: One more time, you're the man. I was looking for this info on internet because I've made it but using JSF 1.2.

Comment: I guess I prematurely assumed I needed a `MethodExpression` because I've seen it done before using `button.setActionExpression(...)`. What's the difference between using `setActionExpression()` and `setAction()`, besides the obvious arguments required?

Comment: @Jake: `setAction()` is the [deprecated](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UICommand.html#setAction(javax.faces.el.MethodBinding)) leftover of JSF 1.x using "deferred EL", which used its own EL implementation with `ValueBinding`, `MethodBinding` and so on (which was later unified with JSP EL). Do **not** use any deprecated API in JSF 2.x at all. They are subject for removal. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812755/difference-between-jsp-el-jsf-el-and-unified-el for a bit of history on EL.

Comment: hmm the button isn't invoking the action, I'll throw up some code

Comment: Code looks fine. Are you implying that an argumentless method get properly invoked?

Comment: No, the function isn't being called at all. There are no errors from attempting to call `displayNode` without arguments, simply nothing happens after clicking the created button

Comment: Then the button is apparently missing after restoring the view. How exactly are you holding `newDiv` in the bean? It should be a request scoped bean and it should be just a property with a normal getter/setter and nothing more (also no lazy loading; JSF will set it by itself). All action methods depending on the manipulated component tree should return `void` or `null` (so that the same view is retained for subsequent request).

Comment: I'm view scoped bean because I build the tree up within the `tree` class, then use these functions to display the nodes. `newDiv` is simply an `HtmlPanelGroup` element, and at the end of the function it is added to an `HtmlPanelGroup topDiv` (soon to change, needs to be a table) that I have bound to a `div` on the JSF page.

Comment: @Jake: a view scoped bean can also, but `UIComponent` isn't serializable, so state saving will fail. If you absolutely need view scoped data, rather split the `UIComponent` property (and the actions depending on it) into a new request scoped bean and inject the view scoped bean as a managed property if you need some data from it.

Comment: Sorry, which `UIComponent` are you referring to?

Comment: Any subclass of `UIComponent`, so also the `newDiv`.

Comment: ok I think I understand, I'll have to try it out tomorrow (5:00 wahoo!)

Comment: Another disadvantage of using `binding` on a view scoped bean is that  a brand new instance will be created on every request. So it's fairly pointless to make it a view scoped one.

Comment: I accepted it because you answered the question I asked (fantastic and thoroughly), but I'll most likely be asking related questions soon XP

Comment: @Balus submit method never is invoked for me on glassfish 4,JSF 2.2,Spring WebFlow and Primefaces. I copied your code as you've written. I've tried add ajax behavior, actionlistener and action on my project but the result is the same...button rendered and useless when I push.

Comment: If I change @BalusC code to SessionScope then method submit is invoked, but requestScope or viewScope not work.