# Dynamic MethodExpression not getting invoked

Tags: java, jsf, binding, el

I have a dynamically created commandButton in a column of a dataTable inside my xhtml, and the methodExpression I defined for it is not getting invoked. Here's the detailed description:

I create the button like this:

```java
Column column = (Column) createComponent(Column.COMPONENT_TYPE);
UIOutput columnTitle = (UIOutput) createComponent(UIOutput.COMPONENT_TYPE);
columnTitle.setValue("Search");
column.getFacets().put("header", columnTitle);
table.getChildren().add(column);

CommandButton button = (CommandButton) createComponent(CommandButton.COMPONENT_TYPE);
button.setIcon("ui-icon-search");
button.setTitle("Search");
button.setUpdate(":mainForm:viewerPanel, :mainForm:growl");

//Action defined here
MethodExpression action = createMethodExpression("#{viewerMB.searchNode(item.value)}", null, Object.class);
button.setActionExpression(action);

column.getChildren().add(button);
```

The button is displayed and the dataTable is rendered normally. by checking the Component Tree I see it all defined in this structure

```
<h:form id="mainForm">
    <p:dialog>
        <p:panel>
            <p:dataTable>
                <p:column>
                    <p:commandButton/>
                <p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </p:panel>
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

**Note:** This isn't my actual code, it's just an example to illustrate the structure inside my page

I create my MethodExpression with the following method found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12098611/dynamic-jsf-2-0-commandbuttons-set-action-with-arguments):

```java
public static MethodExpression createMethodExpression(String expression, Class<?> returnType,
    Class<?>... parameterTypes){
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    return facesContext.getApplication().getExpressionFactory()
        .createMethodExpression(facesContext.getELContext(), expression, returnType, parameterTypes);
}
```

But when I click on the button the method is not invoked, and it is defined in the referenced ManagedBean, here it is:

```java
public void searchNode(Object object){
    try{
        viewer.push(viewerBO.getViewNode(object));
    } catch (BusinessException e){
        FacesUtil.addErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

So it's a void method that receives an Object as argument.

Now here are my doubts:

- Am I creating the MethodExpression the wrong way? is the *item.value* not valid? *item* is the value defined for my dataTable's **var** property
- Am I missing some step here? Perhaps there's something wrong with my tree structure
- Any other thoughts on why it may not be getting invoked?

Comment: As it turns out, it was all working correctly, the problem was with the scope of my _ManagedBean_. I thought a _ViewScoped_ bean would work fine, but as it turns out it didn't. I need a larger scope. It worked with _Session_, but I'll probably have to customize it since _Session_ is too large a scope.