# Can I use Get-Parameter in EL 2.2 without writing it into the Bean?

Tags: jsf-2, el

I want to parse the URL

```
title.xhtml?id=1
```

My code within "title.xhtml" should look like

```
...
<h:outputText value="#{titles.getTitle(${param.id}).id}"></h:outputText>
...
```

But unfortunatelly this does not work, since nested "#" and "$" is not accepted.
So my question is: Can I use an URL parameter and hand it over to a bean function without to store it separately within the bean?

Comment: Just curious, what are you avoiding by not having a bean-property?

Comment: I would have thought that `#{titles.getTitle(param.id).id}` would do it.

Comment: @ Aksel Willgert: the answer #{titles.getTitle(param.id).id} seems to be more readable; 1 line code instead of about 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's invalid EL syntax. You can't and don't need to nest EL expressions in any way. Even nesting `${}` is invalid. The only difference between `#{}` and `${}` is that the `#{}` can perform a *set* operation as well (where applicable), while the `${}` can do only a *get* operation.

This is valid EL syntax:

```
<h:outputText value="#{titles.getTitle(param.id).id}" />
```

Note that `#{param.id}` is fully legal JSF EL syntax. To avoid future confusions, it would be a good idea to make sure that you never use the old JSP EL syntax `${}` in JSF anymore. See also [Difference between JSP EL, JSF EL and Unified EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812755/difference-between-jsp-el-jsf-el-and-unified-el/4812883#4812883).