# loop through an attribute from a javabean

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, jstl, javabeans

I want to print all my products in a table on a JavaServer page but I have troubles with my jstl code.

My Model product:

```
public final class Product
{
    private int id;
    private String description;    
    private Double price;    
    private String categoryName;
...
```

My JavaBean products:
(when this bean is created it's filled with products from my model)

```
@ManagedBean(name = "productsBean")
@RequestScoped
public class Products implements Serializable {

    private List<Product> producten;
    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{applicationBean}")
    private ApplicationBean applicationBean;

    public Producten() {

        Store store = applicationBean.getStore();

    for (String c : store.getCategories()) {
        for(model.Product p : store.getProductsOfCategory(c)){
            beans.Product product = new Product();
            product.setId(p.getId());
            product.setDescription(p.getDescription());
            product.setCategoryName(p.getCategoryName());
            product.setPrice(p.getPrice());
        producten.add(product);
        }

    }                
    }
```

My JavaBean Product:

```
@ManagedBean(name= "productBean")
@RequestScoped
public class Product implements Serializable{

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{applicationBean}")
    private ApplicationBean applicationBean;

     private int product_id;
    private String description;    
    private Double price;    
    private String categoryName;
```

In my JavaServer Page I want something like that but:

```
            <c:forEach var="product" items="${productsBean.products}">
                <tr>
                    <td>${product.description}</td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
```

Comment: You asked similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14154813/javabean-creating)?

Comment: Yes I'm desperately trying to get this work.

Answer (score 0):

The legacy JSP expression `${}` does not auto create JSF managed beans if they do not exist in the scope yet. You need the JSF expression `#{}` instead. Even more, you should *stop* using the legacy JSP expression `${}` in JSF pages to avoid future confusion and maintenance trouble. The JSF expression `#{}` does exactly the same and more (namely, auto creating JSF managed beans and setting model values via input components).

```html
<table>
    <c:forEach var="product" items="#{productsBean.products}">
        <tr>
            <td>#{product.description}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

#### See also:

- [Difference between JSP EL, JSF EL and Unified EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812755/difference-between-jsp-el-jsf-el-and-unified-el)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, have you considered using `<h:dataTable>` instead? It saves you from fiddling with loose HTML `<table>`, `<tbody>`, `<tr>`, `<th>` and `<td>` tags.

```html
<h:dataTable value="#{productsBean.products}" var="product">
    <h:column>#{product.description}</h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

#### See also:

- [Creating master-detail pages for entities, how to link them and which bean scope to choose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459903/jsf-application-correct-use-of-session-scope/8464636#8464636) -- Just the code example

Comment: I use <h:dataTable> now, but my webpage shows literally this "#{product.description}". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you might want to check the servlet specification version number in your web.xml.

Comment: That may happen if you're using JSP instead of Facelets, or if your classpath is a complete mess, or if JSF 2 runs in JSF 1.x fallback modus due to bad configuration. Which resources/tutorials/books are you using while learning JSF2? Based on your previously asked questions I don't have the impression that it's a sane one.

Answer (score -1):

hi did you import the TLD files of jsf jsf core and html

```
<f:view>
<h:form>
<h:dataTable value="#{productsBean.products}" var="product">
<h:column>#{product.description}</h:column>  
</h:dataTable>
```

try like this
Thanks