# Why might a ${variable} reference not be resolved in JSTL?

Tags: jsp, jstl, jspx

In the code below, there are two references to `${labelKey}`, but only one of them is being substituted.

```xml
    <a href="#${labelKey}">
        <spring:message code="${labelKey}.tab.title" />
    </a>
```

After processing, here is the HTML that gets sent to the browser:

```xml
    <a href="#${labelKey}">
        Home
    </a>
```

And what it *should* be is this:

```xml
    <a href="#Home">
        Home
    </a>
```

The first `${labelKey}` reference is not being substituted, but the second one is.  Is `#` an escape character in some environments?  This code has been running fine in several different deployments for almost a year, but a recent deployment on a new server has revealed this problem.

My best guess is there is some kind of environment setting that is different on the new server.  Has anyone seen something like this before?

Comment: Looks like different EL implementation library on your new deployment environment.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [Difference between JSP EL, JSF EL and Unified EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812755/difference-between-jsp-el-jsf-el-and-unified-el)

The different deployment environments that you have are likely using different JSP implementations and that's what you're encountering.