# How can I express hex strings from numbers?

Tags: jsf, hex, el

I'm trying to display a decimal number and hexadecimal number from a sam evalue.

I tried

```
<h:outputText value="#{service.onid} (#{Integer.toHexString(service.onid)})" />
```

The the out is

```
123 ()
```

Comment: So printing this in a class with a 'main' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the syntax `#{Integer.toHexString(...)}` implies that there is a backing bean named Integer available that has a method called toHexString.

See [Difference between JSP EL, JSF EL and Unified EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812755/difference-between-jsp-el-jsf-el-and-unified-el) and follow the 'Related' links to deep dive into the tech specifications of the syntax.

What you are trying to do, I think, is to invoke a script let like in JSP. I don't think you can do that with JSF EL. If you need specific formatting that you want to do with the `service.onid` value, you may want to take a look at the omni faces library functions at http://showcase.omnifaces.org/functions/Numbers.

But seeing that you are trying to do something more involved that pure formatting, I would recommend adding either a variable or function to your backing bean.