# What is the framework's utility / pattern / language that permits to do this

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jstl, dto

I'm using this functionality since a while without knowing why I can use it:
in a jsp page why I can call a getter method of a Dto without the 'get' part?

For example if my Dto class PersonDto has a method called getName(), in my jsp I can do this:

```
 ${person.name}
```

instead of this:

```
 ${person.getName()}
```

Is a characteristic of Spring framework, of MVC pattern, JSTL or a combination of them ? And where can I study this argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Is a characteristic of Spring framework, of MVC pattern, JSTL or a combination of them ?*

None of them. It's called [EL (Expression Language)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/el/package-summary.html).

> *And where can I study this argument?*

Start at [our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info).

---

Noted should be that `${person.getName()}` syntax was **illegal** until EL version 2.2. It's thus certainly not so that `${person.name}` is newer than `${person.getName()}`.

#### See also:

- [Difference between JSP EL, JSF EL and Unified EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812755/difference-between-jsp-el-jsf-el-and-unified-el/)
- [Invoke direct methods or methods with arguments / variables / parameters in EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284236/invoke-direct-methods-or-methods-with-arguments-variables-parameters-in-el/)

Answer (score 1):

It all goes back to the [JavaBeans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans) specification, which demands that for a field named `foo`, there must be a setter `setFoo()` and getter `getFoo()` (or `isFoo()` also permitted for boolean fields).

This allows for frameworks, template languages and other tools to use a simplified syntax, since it is known that `bar.foo` implies `bar.getFoo()`.