Controller unable to pass model values to View page
My viewEmployees method in Controller
        @Autowired
        private EmployeeDao employeeDao;

        @GetMapping("/employees")
        public String viewEmployees(Model model) {
            List<Employee> list = employeeDao.getEmployees();
            for(Employee emp:list) {
            System.out.println("ID: " + emp.getId() + ", Salary: " + emp.getSalary());
            }
            model.addAttribute("list1", list);
            return "view_employees";
        }

My getEmployees method in EmployeeDao :
 public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT * FROM Employee", new RowMapper<Employee>() {
            public Employee mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                Employee employee = new Employee();
                employee.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
                employee.setName(rs.getString("name"));
                employee.setSalary(rs.getDouble("salary")); 
                employee.setDesignation(rs.getString("designation"));
                System.out.println("Employee"+employee);
                return employee;
            }
        });
    }

view_employees.jsp :
<table border="1" class="table">
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Salary</th>
                            <th>Designation</th>
                            <th>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                        <c:forEach var="emp" items="${list1}">
                            <tr>
                                <td>${emp.id}</td>
                                <td>${emp.name}</td>
                                <td>${emp.salary}</td>
                                <td>${emp.designation}</td>
                                <td><a href="employee/${emp.id}">View</a> | <a
                                    href="employee/edit/${emp.id}">Edit</a> | <a
                                    href="employee/delete/${emp.id}">Delete</a></td>
                            </tr>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </table>

Console logs :
Jun 20, 2024 11:02:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log

INFO: Server version name: Apache Tomcat/9.0.71

Jun 20, 2024 11:02:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log

INFO: Server built: Jan 9 2023 22:33:01 UTC

Jun 20, 2024 11:02:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log

INFO: Server version number: 9.0.71.0

Jun 20, 2024 11:02:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log

INFO: OS Name: Windows 10

Jun 20, 2024 11:02:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log

INFO: OS Version: 10.0

Jun 20, 2024 11:02:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log

INFO: Architecture: amd64

Jun 20, 2024 11:02:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log

INFO: Java Home: C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-19

Jun 20, 2024 11:02:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log

INFO: JVM Version: 19.0.2+7-44

Jun 20, 2024 11:02:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log

INFO: JVM Vendor: Oracle Corporation

Jun 20, 2024 11:02:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log

INFO: CATALINA_BASE: D:\\Java Kit\\DSAEclipsWS\\.metadata\\.plugins\\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\\tmp0

Jun 20, 2024 11:02:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log

INFO: CATALINA_HOME: C:\\Apache Tomcat 9.0\\apache-tomcat-9.0.71

Jun 20, 2024 11:02:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log

INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=D:\\Java Kit\\DSAEclipsWS\\.metadata\\.plugins\\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\\tmp0

Jun 20, 2024 11:02:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log

INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\\Apache Tomcat 9.0\\apache-tomcat-9.0.71

Jun 20, 2024 11:02:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log

INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=D:\\Java Kit\\DSAEclipsWS\\.metadata\\.plugins\\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\\tmp0\\wtpwebapps

Jun 20, 2024 11:02:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log

INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED

Jun 20, 2024 11:02:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log

INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED

Jun 20, 2024 11:02:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log

INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED

Jun 20, 2024 11:02:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log

INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED

Jun 20, 2024 11:02:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log

INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED

Jun 20, 2024 11:02:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log

INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

Jun 20, 2024 11:02:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log

INFO: Command line argument: -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages

Jun 20, 2024 11:02:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent

INFO: The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path: \[C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-19\\bin;C:\\Windows\\Sun\\Java\\bin;C:\\Windows\\system32;C:\\Windows;C:\\app\\abc\\product\\21c\\dbhomeXE\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Python312\\Scripts\\;C:\\Program Files\\Python312\\;C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath;C:\\Windows\\system32;C:\\Windows;C:\\Windows\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\100\\Tools\\Binn\\VSShell\\Common7\\IDE\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\100\\Tools\\Binn\\;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\100\\Tools\\Binn\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\100\\DTS\\Binn\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\\Common7\\IDE\\PrivateAssemblies\\;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft\\Web Platform Installer\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft ASP.NET\\ASP.NET Web Pages\\v1.0\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.0\\Windows Performance Toolkit\\;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\110\\Tools\\Binn\\;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\150\\Tools\\Binn\\;C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\;C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-19\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-19\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Shell 8.0\\bin\\;C:\\Users\\abc\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps;C:\\Users\\abc\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\bin;C:\\Users\\abc\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm;C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.2.2\\bin;;C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm Community Edition 2023.3.4\\bin;;.\]

Jun 20, 2024 11:02:07 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init

INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler \["http-nio-8080"\]

Jun 20, 2024 11:02:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load

INFO: Server initialization in \[3217\] milliseconds

Jun 20, 2024 11:02:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal

INFO: Starting service \[Catalina\]

Jun 20, 2024 11:02:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal

INFO: Starting Servlet engine: \[Apache Tomcat/9.0.71\]

Jun 20, 2024 11:02:08 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom

WARNING: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using \[SHA1PRNG\] took \[122\] milliseconds.

Jun 20, 2024 11:02:14 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars

INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.

Jun 20, 2024 11:02:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log

INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath

Jun 20, 2024 11:02:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log

INFO: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcher'

Jun 20, 2024 11:02:15 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean

INFO: Initializing Servlet 'dispatcher'

Jun 20, 2024 11:02:18 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean

INFO: Completed initialization in 3245 ms

Jun 20, 2024 11:02:18 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start

INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler \["http-nio-8080"\]

Jun 20, 2024 11:02:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start

INFO: Server startup in \[10578\] milliseconds

EmployeeEmployee \[id=1, name=Yogesh, salary=300000.0, designation=IT Manager\]

EmployeeEmployee \[id=3, name=Sarvesh, salary=100000.0, designation=Manager\]

EmployeeEmployee \[id=4, name=Bhavna, salary=25000.0, designation=Director\]

EmployeeEmployee \[id=5, name=Akansha, salary=10000.0, designation=Executive\]

EmployeeEmployee \[id=6, name=Anshik, salary=50000.0, designation=Fin Manager\]

EmployeeEmployee \[id=7, name=Samiksha, salary=100000.0, designation=Manager\]

ID: 1, Salary: 300000.0

ID: 3, Salary: 100000.0

ID: 4, Salary: 25000.0

ID: 5, Salary: 10000.0

ID: 6, Salary: 50000.0

ID: 7, Salary: 100000.0

output in webpage :
 ID           Name            Salary                Designation            Actions

${emp.id}  ${emp.name}  ${emp.salary}  ${emp.designation}   View | Edit | Delete

I want to print employee list on webpage but not getting on the webpage.

What is the view technology you are using? What version of spring (boot) are you using, configuration, dependencies. There are only some small code snippets in here, which lack context and the ability to build a full picture of the moving parts.

Do you have a <!DOCTYPE> line in top of your web.xml?

Do you have the c: tag reference at the top of your JSP? Do you have the JSTL dependency? It looks like your list has the objects you expect, but you're getting only 1 row in the page, with the $ references having no values. The 1 row makes me think maybe the <c:forEach> isn't understood.

@BalusC 

Remove that line. See abovelinked duplicate for technical explanation. Less is more.

@dbreaux: Since JSP version 2.0 (released at 2003!), JSTL is not anymore necessary for functioning of EL in JSP. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/4812755.

@M.Deinum you can check my complete project from https://github.com/ypandey9/MVCCRUDOPSJDBCTEmplate

Please find my complete project and suggest https://github.com/ypandey9/MVCCRUDOPSJDBCTEmplate

@dbreaux please check my project from https://github.com/ypandey9/MVCCRUDOPSJDBCTEmplate and suggest.
