# jsp JSTI foreach: array from request.setAttribute

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, foreach, jstl

I am wondering how I can iterate through a list array in a jsp page, where the list is defined in a custom java servlet.

This is what I have in the servlet:

```
request.setAttribute("TITLE", STRINGVALUE);
```

I can display the above code fragment with the following line:

`${dashboard}`

Now I am trying to use a foreach loop:

```
<c:forEach var="VARIABLE" items="??????">
```

The question consists of two sub questions:

1. How can I use an array in the foreach statement, without using scriptlets?
2. How can I print values of the array elements? For example, ${person.name} results in an error, as the program only sees a String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you need to have the List of your Objects in your session.

Ex.

```
List <Persons> myList = new ArrayList<Persons>();
myList.add(p1);
myList.add(p2);
session.setAttribute("persons", myList );
```

And then in your jsp you use it like this:

```
<c:forEach items="${persons}" var="personBean">  
  ${personBean.lastName}, ${personBean.firstName} <br />  
</c:forEach>
```

You can also see BalusC post in [Iterate over elements of List and Map using JSTL <c:forEach> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148658/java-list-use-through-use-of-jstl-cforeach) for more info