# How to show complete table values from database in jsp select tag using java

Tags: java, database, jsp

I have a form made in jsp page, which allows user to store some values of a product like name, category & many more.

Below is my form in a brief way:

```
            <div class="element">
                    <label for="element">Product name </label>
                    <input id="name" name="name" class="text  err" />       
                </div>


                    <div class="element">
                    <label for="category">Category </label>                     
                    <select id='stateCombo'  onchange='stateComboChange();'>
       <option value='-1' title='-select one-'>-select one-</option>
       <option value='0' title='Mobile'>Mobile</option>
       <option value='1' title='Nsw'>Routers</option>
      <option value='2' title='Tas'>Datacard</option>
      <option value='' title='Tas'><%=request.getAttribute("category") %></option>

    </select>
                                              </div>
```

Now my main focus is on category element. I want to show category values from db as option within select tag. I have used list in request.setAttribute("category",list) where list contains category name values from db.

But my output shows like:

```
  [universe.shopping.dto.Category@33008c73]
   [universe.shopping.dto.Category@33008c73, universe.shopping.dto.Category@6904ec2d]


          "universe.shopping.dto.----"   this is my bean class package
```

I have created bean class and using list i'am getting values from db.

In short i need to know best possible way to store values from database within option in a drop down manner within select tag.

Comment: did my answer work for you? Would appreciate it if you could indicate it with the checkmark.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just print a list as it is in jsp. What your output shows is the reference to the list and not the actual values in the list.

you can loop through the list using jstl tags as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2148672/728610).