# How to calculate the total of a sum in JSTL

Tags: jsp, foreach, sum, jstl

How can I realise this with JSP and JSTL?

```
int total = 0;
for (Article article : list) {
    total += article.price;
}
```

Comment: Just like above. Use <c:set> to set total. Use <c:forEach> for loop.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `<c:set>` to initialize the total variable, use `<c:forEach>` to iterate over list and use another `<c:set>` to add the iterated value to the total.

```
<c:set var="total" value="${0}"/>
<c:forEach var="article" items="${list}">
    <c:set var="total" value="${total + article.price}" />
</c:forEach>
```

See also [Iterate over elements of List and Map using JSTL <c:forEach> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148658/java-list-use-through-use-of-jstl-cforeach).

Comment: It is a mistake, I editted answer. Also it is recommended that to assign integer value to variable use like this, value="${0}"