# How to generate list of checkboxes by iterating java List?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

My Java code,

```
public ModelAndView getDefault(ModelAndView mav,@RequestParam(value = "QueryCode", 
required = false, defaultValue = "207") String QueryCode) {
    List<String> list=  columnService.getColumnName(QueryCode);
    mav.addObject("columnList",list);
    return mav;
}
```

I tried something like this in JSP,

```
<c:set var="jspList" value="${columnList}" />
<%
     for(int i = 0; i < jspList.length; i++){
%>
<input type="checkbox" name="<%= jspList[i]%>"><br/>
<%
     }
%>
```

but it didn't work and I am getting error like,

> cannot resolve symbol jspList.

Comment: Use the JSTL <c:foreach> ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148658/iterate-over-elements-of-list-and-map-using-jstl-cforeach-tag )

Comment: Looks like you've extra space, please change from `<%= jspList[i]%>` to `<%=jspList[i]%>`. You can use EL as well like, `<input type="checkbox" name="${jspList}">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `c:forEach`:

```
<c:forEach items="${columnList}" var="item">
   <input type="checkbox" name="${item}">
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Thank you this generated the checkbox, i also added <input type="checkbox" name="${item}">${item}<br> so i get the text.