# Can't iterate over list in Jsp

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am using hibernate to get the subjects associated with a particular user. In mainPage, I want to see firstName and LastName (this works) of the user and allowed subjects. But, for some reason, I am not able to successfully iterate over the list of subjects put in mainPage.

In my Spring controller I have a method, which looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/signin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String SignIn(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, ModelMap modelMap){

        String username = user.getUsername();
        String password = user.getPassword();

        User user1 = userService.getUser(username, password);
        if(user1 != null){

            List<Subject> subjectList = userService.getUserSubjects(user1.getId());

            modelMap.addAttribute("subjects", subjectList);
            modelMap.addAttribute("user", user1);
            return "mainPage";
        }

        modelMap.addAttribute("ShowNotAuthenticated", true);
        return "authentication";
    }
```

`mainPage.jsp` looks like this:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Current user: ${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}</h2> //this works
        <br>
        <h3>Allowed subjects:</h3>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Subject Name
            </td>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${subjects}" var="x"> //doesn't work
            <tr>
                <td>
                    ${x.name}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is `SignIn` method during debug:

[image]

These are pictures in `mainPage.jsp`:

[image]

[image]

`Mykhailo Moskura`'s suggestion doesn't work too:

[image]

Comment: You are getting a list of `Subject` into that variable so, maybe, you are trying to print something you don't have. As you see, the're are 0=> something, 1=> Physics, etc... and the NumberFormatException shows you're trying to process something different from what you expect, Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148658/iterate-over-elements-of-list-and-map-using-jstl-cforeach-tag

Comment: @Alfabravo, you are right, `${x[1]}` works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From debugger screenshot I see that your `subjectList` has elements of type `Object[]`. So you either need to change what you store in that list or try to use `${x[1]}` instead of `${x.name}`.

Comment: To tell that code of `userService.getUserSubjects()` is needed