# Pass html element value to servlet

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, web-applications

I have an HTML page that takes text input of the file path and that input process by the getOwner() of a Detail class in servlet. This servlet creates an HTML dropdown menu with all the local users in a computer fetched from the getACL() in the same servlet. Now if a user selects a specific user and the checkbox having different permission, how to get the selected value in the dropdown menu and checkbox to be processed by modifyACL() in Detail class.

```
public class Details {
    native String[] getACL(String s);
    native String getOwner(String name); 
    native void modifyACL(String s, String k, int i);
    static{
      System.loadLibrary("Details");
   }}
```

Servlet class

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class ACL extends HttpServlet{
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res)throws ServletException,IOException  
    {  
       Details obj =new Details();
       int len;
       System.load("C:\\Users\\pradeep-pt3689\\eclipse-workspace\\FilePermission\\jni\\Details.dll");
       String pathDir = req.getParameter("path");
       res.setContentType("text/html");//setting the content type
       PrintWriter pw=res.getWriter();//get the stream to write the data  
       pw.println("<html><body><center>");
       pw.println("Welcome to servlet,File owner is: <b>");
       pw.println(obj.getOwner(pathDir));
       pw.println("</b><br><br>");
       String[] prop = obj.getACL(pathDir);
       pw.println("The File property is ::<br><table><tr><th>User or Group Name</th><th>Permission</th></tr>");
       len=prop.length;
       String[] arr = new String[len];
       for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
       {
         String[] parts=prop[i].split("\\\\");
         arr[i]=parts[0]+"\\"+parts[1];
         pw.println("<tr><td>");
         pw.println(arr[i]);
         pw.println("</td><td>");
         if(parts[2].contains("Full Control"))
         {
             pw.println("<label><input type='checkbox' name='property' value='FullControl' checked='checked'/>Full Control</label>"
                    + "<label><input type='checkbox' name='property' value='Read'/>Read</label>"
                    + "<label><input type='checkbox' name='property' value='Write'/>Write</label>"
                    + "<label><input type='checkbox' name='property' value='Execute'/>Execute</label>");
         } 
         else
         {
            pw.println("<label><input type='checkbox' name='property' value='FullControl'/>Full Control</label>");
            if(parts[2].contains("Read")){
                pw.println("<label><input type='checkbox' name='property' value='Read' checked='checked'/>Read</label>");
            }
            if(parts[2].contains("Execute")) {
                pw.println("<label><input type='checkbox' name='property' value='Read' checked='checked'/>Execute</label>");
            }
            if(parts[2].contains("Write")) {
                pw.println("<label><input type='checkbox' name='property' value='Read' checked='checked'/>Write</label>");
            }
         }
         pw.println("<td></tr>");
       }
       pw.println("</table>");
       pw.println("<hr>");
       pw.println("Enter details to modify ACL<br><br>");
       pw.println("<label for='user'>Select a user:</label><select name='user'>");
       for(int j=0;j<len;j++) {
           pw.println("<option value='");
           pw.println(arr[j]);
           pw.println("'>");
           pw.println(arr[j]);
           pw.println("</option>");
       }
       pw.println("</select>&nbsp;");
       pw.println("<label><input type='checkbox' name='modifyProperty' value='FullControl' checked='checked'/>Full Control</label>"
            + "<label><input type='checkbox' name='modifyProperty' value='Read'/>Read</label>"
            + "<label><input type='checkbox' name='modifyProperty' value='Write'/>Write</label>"
            + "<label><input type='checkbox' name='modifyProperty' value='Execute'/>Execute</label>");
       pw.println("</center></body></html>");
       pw.close();//closing the stream  
    }
}
```

[image: output]

I have to get selected value of second part in given page image.

Comment: You need to pass the selected value of user and checkbox in `modifyACL..` ? If yes you need to submit that then you can access the same

Comment: yeah exactly. How to get those values? Since it's not defined as a separate JSP page element sending those values for processing. @Swati

Comment: put your inputs under `form` tags i.e : `out.println("<form method = "POST" action = "yourservlet">");...//your select-box and checkbox    out.println("</form>");` . Also add a submit button inside `form` and get value in `doPost` method of servlet and write your modification code there.But , i would suggest you to write these HTML codes in jsp not servlet .

Comment: Thanks a lot. This seems to be work. I will try and let know. BTW is there any other way like sending the string array as a parameter in a different jsp page and then creating a drop-down menu there using this array parameter value?

Comment: Yes you can do that as well . Put that array value in `request.setAttribute()` and pass the same to jsp page .Also to access the same in jsp page use [jstl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148658/iterate-over-elements-of-list-and-map-using-jstl-cforeach-tag)

Comment: For populating the drop down value in jsp shoul I use something like this request.setAttribute("courses", courses); <select name="cid" id="cid" >
    <c:forEach items="${courses}" var="course">
        <option value="${course}">${course}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select> Is this will be correct? @Swati

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219201/discussion-between-swati-and-margie).