# Two dimensional arraylist with c:foreach jstl tag

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

I'm using a two dimension arraylist in two imbricated JSTL `<c:forEach>`:

```
<select multiple size="30">
    <c:forEach var="uri" items="${defaultResult}" varStatus="iterator">
        <c:forEach var="cate" items="${defaultResult[iterator.index]}">
         <option value="${defaultResult[iterator.index][0]}"> ${cate}[1]</option>
        </c:forEach> 
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

but the indexes seem not to be working, for example the values returned by `${cate}[1]` are all the values of any dimension followed by `[1]`

If you have any idea to solve my problem it would be helpful.

Answer (score 6):

It needs to go inside the expression, not outside.

```
${cate[1]}
```

---

By the way, why don't you just access the `var` of the first loop?

```
<c:forEach var="uri" items="${defaultResult}">
    <c:forEach var="cate" items="${uri}">
        <option value="${uri[0]}">${cate[1]}</option>
    </c:forEach> 
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Yes but when I do that I've got an exception : GRAVE: "Servlet.service()"for the servlet LinkedServlet generated an exception
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'java.lang.String' does not have the property '1'

Comment: So `${cate}` is actually a `String`? Verify the code logic of prepopulating the `${defaultResult}`. Apparently you're filling it with `List#toString()` instead of `List`.

Comment: Yes you're right but I can't remove the toString() so I'll try to put my data in a map

Comment: Uhm, not being able to remove it indicates a much bigger problem. Why can't you do this?

Comment: Because I'm using jena library to get the result of some SPARQL queries and it doesn't allow me to get the result without anything at the end.

Comment: Thank you for your answers now it works with a linkedHashMap thanks to that tutorial http://www.tech-freaks.in/Java-Programming/Rapid-Code/iterate-map-jstl-el.html

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835683/loop-through-hashmap-java-jsp

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me:

.java:

```
private int[][] childAges; // [room][child] = age
.....
```

.jsp:

```
<c:forEach var="childAge" items="${childAges}" >
    <c:forEach var="age" items="${childAge}" >
        ${age}
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```