# Java JSP/JSTL Loop through objects 2d boolean array

Tags: java, arrays, jsp, servlets, jstl

## Problem:

I want to iterate through the array of the "Seating" class.

#### "Seating" Code:

```
public class Seating {
private int nRow, nCol;
private boolean[][] seats;

public Seating () {
    nRow = 8;
    nCol = 8;
    seats = new boolean[nRow][nCol];
}
```

An instance of "Seating" is created by the "EventBooking" class shown below.

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    seats = new Seating(8,8);

    seats.setSeatStatus(0,1);
    seats.setSeatStatus(1,1);

    request.setAttribute("seats", seats.seats);
    RequestDispatcher req = request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
    req.forward(request,response);
```

And the **.jsp** that is supposed to be looping through these values.

```
<c:forEach var = "row" items = "${seats}">
    <c:forEach var = "col" items = "${row}">
        <c:out value = "${seats}"/>
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

I am trying to *send* my **"Seating"** object to the **.jsp**. The **.jsp** will then loop through the values of Seating's 2D array. Each of the array's values will be printed.

#### Error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing [/index.jsp] at line [8]
```

And line 8.

```
8:  <c:forEach var = "row" items = "${seats}">
```

Any help is appreciated.

**Edit**
**Full "Seating" code**

```
public class Seating {
private int nRow, nCol;
public boolean[][] seats;

public Seating () {
    nRow = 8;
    nCol = 8;
    seats = new boolean[nRow][nCol];
}

public Seating (int row, int col) {
    nRow = row;
    nCol = col;
    seats = new boolean[row][col];
}

public boolean seatStatus (int row, int col) {
    return seats[row][col];
}

public void setSeatStatus (int row, int col) {
    if (seats[row][col] == false) {
        seats[row][col] = true;
    }
    else if (seats[row][col] == true) {
        seats[row][col] = false;
    }
    //else
        //Error
}

public int getRowLength () {
    return nRow;
}

public int getColLength () {
    return nCol;
}
```

Comment: Couple syntax errors I notice offhand: `seats = new Seating(8,8);` is not a valid way to instantiate a class; it should be `seats = new Seating`.  Also, is `setSeatStatus()` defined in the `Seating` class?  Finally, which is line 8 in your `index.jsp`?

Comment: @C.Peck Disregard syntax errors, I included only the relevant code to make it easier to read. The code compiles. Line 8 is shown at the bottom of original post.

Comment: Still I don't think you can instantiate `Seating` as you have.  Java Classes don't accept arguments.   It won't compile unless you instantiate it with `seats = new Seating;`

Comment: It does compile, as I stated. 

The second constructor has the appropriate arguments. It has been committed because there is no real need to show it as it is not entirely relevant to the question posed.

Comment: Sorry, but unless I have massively overestimated my knowledge of Java there is no way that code would compile.  In addition to the incorrect instantiation of the `Seating` class, `public Seating ()` is not a valid method signature as you have not provided a return type (it should be `void`) and the space after `Seating` must be deleted.  Just curious what you are referring to as the "second constructor"?

Comment: I think you may have massively overestimated your knowledge of Java. 1) It's a constructor, it requires no return type. 2) The space between the parentheses and function name makes 0 difference. Try it for yourself.

Comment: Perhaps I have, but I just tried to declare a Java method with `public Seating ()` and I received the following compilation error:

   `error: invalid method declaration; return type required
    public Seating () {
           ^
1 error`

Do you want to see a screenshot?

Comment: @C.Peck I've included the full code for that class, however I feel that further discussion on this is redundant as it's not related to my issue as the code compiles perfectly.

Comment: My mistake, you are correct that I have massively overestimated my understanding of Java.  Sorry for wasting your time and thank you for uploading the whole class.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this and correct the innermost loop output - [Two dimensional arraylist with c:foreach jstl tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187885/two-dimensional-arraylist-with-cforeach-jstl-tag)

Moreover, you can print 2d array via index such as a[1][0] to see whether you got any value present in them.