# How to do a foreach loop in a LinkedHashMap in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, foreach, linkedhashmap

I do not have much experience with jsp.
In java I can do, but it is not good to open a block <% %>

Comment: Why is it not good to open a block? Show us how you'd do it in java...

Comment: You can write code in a JSP. And you can call a method in a class to do your loop if you want to avoid cluttering your JSP.

Comment: @ControlAltDel, As per jsp specification, scriptlets need to be avoided if possible. Read this answer from BalusC http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files?lq=1

Comment: @ControlAltDel: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835683/how-to-loop-through-a-hashmap-in-jsp

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use JSTL foreach to iterate over the HashMap.

```
<c:forEach var="type" items="${yourMap}">
   Key is ${type.key}
   Value is ${type.value}
</c:forEach>
```

NOTE: If you are using Tomcat, you need to explicitly copy JSTL lib to classpath. With other servers I know of default comes with JSTL.