# c:forEach don't repeat same values when already present in previous row

Tags: jsp, foreach, jstl

I'm having some trouble with this...

I have code like this:

```
Market market = new market();
List<Market > list = marketService.getMarketItemList(market);
model.addAttribute("list", list);
```

I have a table like this:

```
type      |  item_name

fruit     |  Banana

fruit     |  Apple

vegetable |  Onion
```

And I have coded a *for each* in my JSP like this:

```
<c:forEach var="cmenu" items="${list}">
    <li><a href="${url_itemmarket}/${cmenu.itemName}">${cmenu.description}/a>/li>
</c:forEach>
```

In the JSP, I want it to look like this:

```
type      |  Item Name

Fruit     |  Banana

          |  Apple

Vegetable |  Onion
```

I don't want to repeat value *fruit* **in jsp view**.

Can anyone help me to get an example or some references for this?

Thanks!

Comment: This is pure jsp or anything

Comment: i think this can use for each,,,but maybe need modification

Comment: You could do it with a simple foreach, but it will get messy.  You'd have to keep track of the previous type and determine whether or not it has changed for each row.  If you use a Map it will be much cleaner.  You can iterate over each key (which would be a type) and then print the associated list of fruit names, markets, etc...

Comment: i alredy use hashmap but still same.. key = fruit | value = banana the output still same..

Comment: If you're already using a HashMap, you're using `<c:forEach>` wrong.  Take a look at the answer I link to in my answer.  It shows how to use `<c:forEach>` tag with a Map (note that the `var` in the loop is actually of type `MapEntry`).  The example code you've shared makes it look like you're using a list (not a Map).  I also added a bunch of example code to my answer...

Comment: I'm not sure if these are typos or not, but you have two errors in your JSP: `/a>` and `/li>` is incorrect.  I'll edit my answer to talk about that, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.

You have some errors in your HTML:

```
<li><a href="${url_itemmarket}/${cmenu.itemName}">${cmenu.description}/a>/li>
                                                                      ^  ^
                                                                      |  |
    two errors here (mising < characters) --------------------------------

    replace with this -----------------------------------------------------
                                                                      |   |
                                                                      v   v
<li><a href="${url_itemmarket}/${cmenu.itemName}">${cmenu.description}</a></li>
```

2.

You should use a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

The keys of the map should be the different *types*.

The values should be *Lists* of Food objects.

Then you can iterate over the keys of the map in your JSP.

**You'll need a nested loop to iterate over the Foods in each List.**

I think your JSP/JSTL would look something like this, but it's untested:

```
<table>
  <tr><th>type</th><th>Item Name</th></tr>
  <!-- iterate over each key in the map -->
  <c:forEach var="foodMapEntry" items="${foodMap}">
    <tr>
      <td>${foodMapEntry.key}</td>
      <td>
        <!-- iterate over each item in the list of foods -->
        <c:forEach var="food" items="${foodMapEntry.value}">         
          | ${food.name}<br/>         
        </c:forEach>
      </td>
    </tr>   
  </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Here's some code that shows how to build the map used above:

```
/* create a list of food */
List<Food> foodList = new ArrayList<Food>();

/* add some fruits to the list */
foodList.add(new Food("Banana", "fruit"));
foodList.add(new Food("Apple", "fruit"));

/* add some veggies to the list */
foodList.add(new Food("Onion", "vegetable"));
foodList.add(new Food("Mushroom", "vegetable"));

/* add some candy to the list */
foodList.add(new Food("Chocolate", "candy"));
foodList.add(new Food("Gummy Bears", "candy"));

/* create a Map that maps food types to lists of Food objects */
Map<String, List<Food>> foodMap = new HashMap<String, List<Food>>();

/* populate the map */
for (Food f : foodList) {
    String foodType = f.getType();
    if (foodMap.containsKey(foodType)) {
        foodMap.get(foodType).add(f);
    }
    else {
       List<Food> tempList = new ArrayList<Food>();
       tempList.add(f);
       foodMap.put(foodType, tempList);
    }
}
```

And a simple Food class:

```
class Food {
   private String name;
   private String type;

   public Food(String n, String t) {
       name = n;
       type = t;
   }

   public String getName() { return name; }
   public String getType() { return type; }
}
```

Here's a [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1835683/778118) about using Maps with JSP and JSTL.

Comment: I don't know if that `|` symbol is allowed in the JSP... You might want to try without that first ;-) Unforunately I can't test anything I typed above, so there may be errors.

Comment: this works thanks!!..and thanks to help me fixed my Question..! my english bad >,<" You rockkkk... ^_^

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot create a map, so if you need to work with a list, you can check the previous value.

You can create a variable containing the previous value and check for that:

```
<c:set var="types" value="${['fruit','fruit','vegetable']}"/>
<c:forEach items="${types}" var="type">
  ${type eq previousType ? '-same-' : type}<br/>
  <c:set var="previousType" value="${type}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Or, you could use the index using the `varStatus` attribute:

```
<c:set var="types" value="${['fruit','fruit','vegetable']}"/>
<c:forEach items="${types}" var="type" varStatus="status">
  ${status.index gt 0 and types[status.index - 1] eq types[status.index] ? '-same-' : type}<br/>
</c:forEach>
```

Here you could also use `not status.first` instead of `status.index gt 0`.

Both will output:

```
fruit
-same-
vegetable
```

Answer (score 0):

Store your data like this:

```
Map<String, List<String>> data = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```