# How to display HashMap Key in jsp/jstl

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jstl

I am new to JSP/JSTL.

I have set a HashMap on request as follows

```
HashMap <String, Vector> hmUsers = new HashMap<String, Vector>();

HashMap hmUsers = eQSessionListener.getLoggedinUsers();

request.setAttribute("currentLoggedInUsersMap", hmUsers);
```

I am alerting HashMap in My jsp as follows

```
<script> alert("<c:out value = '${currentLoggedInUsersMap}' />"); </script>
```

All works as per my expectations till now.

But if I try to get key of this HashMap as follow then nothing is alerted.

```
<script> alert("<c:out value = '${currentLoggedInUsersMap.key}' />"); </script>
```

Is there anything I am going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is as follow ??

Comment: Are u abke to see my code ?

Answer (score 6):

This is what you need to iterate the Map in JSP. For more info have a look at [JSTL Core c:forEach Tag](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_foreach_tag.htm).

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<c:forEach items="${currentLoggedInUsersMap}" var="entry">
    Key = ${entry.key}, value = ${entry.value}<br>
</c:forEach>
```

It's just like a Map.Entry that is used in JAVA as shown below to get the key-value.

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : currentLoggedInUsersMap.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    String value = entry.getValue();
}
```

Read detained description here on [How to loop through a HashMap in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835683/how-to-loop-through-a-hashmap-in-jsp)

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over hashmap as:

```
    <c:forEach items="${currentLoggedInUsersMap}" var="usersMap" varStatus="usersMapStatus">  
        //Key
        Key: ${usersMap.key}
        //Iterate over values ,assuming vector of strings
        <c:forEach items="${usersMap.value}" var="currentLoggedInUserValue" varStatus="valueStatus">
            Value: ${currentLoggedInUserValue}
        </c:forEach>        
    </c:forEach>
```

Here ${usersMap.key} is the list of keys present in the map and ${usersMap.value} is the vector which you have to iterate again in an inner loop as shown above.

Make sure to import:

```
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Comment: What do you think about `c:out` that is used in OP post? does it require to import in again. ;)

Comment: @Braj I said to "make sure" and that means not to import again if already done so  :)

Comment: What is `varStatus`?