# Not able to do type cast in JSP code

Tags: java, jsp, java-8

This JSP code was working fine in java 8, but not able to run same in java 8.

```
<c:set var="sAttrib" value="${bean.attrib}" /><% iteratorVal 
((LinkedHashMap)sAttrib).keySet().iterator();   while(iteratorVal.hasNext()) 
{ key = (Integer) iteratorVal.next();  currDev = (Entity)
((LinkedHashMap)sAttrib).get(key);%>
```

I am getting error as:

`sAttrib`  cannot be resolved.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to uninstall  java 8 and install java 8

Comment: Did you import the core taglib?

Comment: this [POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24752240/how-to-iterate-spring-properties-as-a-jsp-list/24752322#24752322) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `<c:set var="sAttrib" value="${bean.attrib}" />` you create what is called a scoped variable, here in page context. You cannot use it directly in scriptlet.

Anyway for you use case, **do not use scriptlet** but use directly `${bean.attrib}` in a foreach :

```
<c:forEach var="iterator" items="${bean.attrib}">
    ...
</c:forEach>
```

If you **really** need to to something in java with a scoped variable you must first get it from its scope :

```
Map attrib = pageContext.findAttribute("sAttrib");
```

Or directly :

```
Map attrib = pageContext.findAttribute("bean").getAttrib();
```