# How to solve IllegalArgumentException: Property is not indexed

Tags: java, jsp, exception, struct, properties

I have a property in jsp like the following

```
   <html:text property="sequenceNumbersMap[0]"  styleId="sequenceNumbersMap[0]" value="0"/>
   <html:text property="sequenceNumbersMap[1]"  styleId="sequenceNumbersMap[1]" value="1"/>
   <html:text property="sequenceNumbersMap[2]"  styleId="sequenceNumbersMap[2]" value="2"/>
   <html:text property="sequenceNumbersMap[3]"  styleId="sequenceNumbersMap[3]" value="3"/>
```

and `ActionForm` has the property like

Map sequenceNumbersMap;

and `getter/setter`

```
public Map<Integer, Integer> getSequenceNumbersMap() {
        return sequenceNumbersMap;
    }

    public void setSequenceNumbersMap(Map<Integer, Integer> sequenceNumbersMap) {
        this.sequenceNumbersMap = sequenceNumbersMap;
    }
```

but when i try to submit the jsp i get the following exception :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'sequenceNumbersMap' is not indexed
```

would someone help me to fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Map is not an array!

Answer (score 1):

A map is not ordered so `sequenceNumbersMap[i]` does not mean anything. If you mean to get the value mapped to `i` rather than getting the `i`-th item in the map (which has no sense again), you can do it with `sequenceNumbersMap.get(i)`.

Answer (score 0):

You must either iterate through a map differently: [How to loop through a HashMap in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835683/how-to-loop-through-a-hashmap-in-jsp)

Or use a different kind of data structure for sequence numbers (indexed, as it was pointed in the exception, e.g. java.util.List).