# Jsp el retrieve value from map

Tags: jsp, hashmap, el

I have created a working java-bean and put it inside a map that i stored into an attribute of the session

```
Bean bean = new Bean(LocalDate.now(), "super event", 1000);
request.getSession().setAttribute("userMap"
            , new HashMap<String, Bean>().put("bean", bean));
```

Then from jsp file i try to retrieve it like this `${userMap[bean].date }` or like this `${userMap[0].date }` but it doesn't work.

Comment: I tried all of those examples it doesn't work

Comment: Try following way :

http://stackoverflow.com/a/1835742/3226981