# JSP- Dynamic option select value

Tags: java, jsp

I have 2 option in my jsp file. First option comobox,

```
<select name="firstoption">
    <option value="select">-Select-</option>
    <option value="apple">APPLE</option>
    <option value="android">ANDROID</option>
</select>
```

and when I select the `apple` option, the second dropdown will be

```
<select name="secondoption">
    <option value="select">-Select-</option>
    <option value="iphone">Iphone</option>
    <option value="ipod">Ipod</option>
</select>
```

If I select the `android` menu, the second dropdown will be another option list.

can anybody help me with this? thanks. and sorry for my bad english

Comment: I don't know how many options there will be but using a map of maps should do the trick.

Comment: do you have any reference link?

Comment: Generally displaying data from a map is explained in the answer to this [SO-Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835683/how-to-loop-through-a-hashmap-in-jsp). After selecting the first value you need an ajax call to read the values for the second select. There are a lot of examples around if you google a bit. ;-)